# Converting exponential value in java to a number format

Tags: java

I am trying to read the values from excel sheet using java. When i type more than 10 letters in a cell in excel it is displaying in exponential form like "9.78313E+2". but this is  not the real number what i given.
Can any body help me out in this. How can i convert the above exponential form to original number using java language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should show us the number you have in the excel and the result in Java.

Comment: `9.78313E+2` = `978.313` Are you confusing value with format. `double` doesn't preserve the format only the value.

Answer (score 22):

You can convert as follows,
for example:

```
new BigDecimal("406770000244E+12").toBigInteger();
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Double.parseDouble("9.78313E+2");
```

gives me

```
978.313
```

For more info see [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29).

Following your further queries below, if you've entered `4256411411` and Excel is presenting this as `4.26E+09`, putting that value into `parseDouble()` will only give you `4260000000`. If you want the original, perhaps you need to output the Excel file in a fuller format for your Java program, and/or query it using a Java/Excel API (e.g. POI)

Comment: yes. it gives but this is not the original number what i given in the excel sheet

Comment: I tried this one with BigDecimal also. It is also giving same answer

Comment: Can you show us what the exact number is? And are you fetching the number from excel sheet in your Java code?

Comment: this is the value i given in the cell in excel sheet "4256411411" but it displaying "4.26E+09". By using java i need to convert that exponential value to original value. yes i am fetching the values from excel sheet using java code

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, but none of the answers above `Double.parseDouble()` and `Double.valueOf()`... solved my problem, and I continued to get the exponential 'E' value...

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java/41285611#41285611) link has a much better approach for the problem, and as I've written there - there is a very good solution:

I needed to convert some double to currency values, and fount that most to the solution are OK but not for me.

The `DecimalFormat` was eventually the way for me, so here is what I've done:

```
   public String foo(double value) //Got here 6.743240136E7 or something..
    {
        DecimalFormat formatter;

        if(value - (int)value > 0.0)
            formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); //Here you can also deal with rounding if you wish..
        else
            formatter = new DecimalFormat("0");

        return formatter.format(value);
    }
```

As you can see, if the number is natural I get - say - 20000000 instead of 2E7 (etc) - without any decimal point.

and if it's decimal, I get only 2 decimal digits.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `BigDecimal`, if you want the exact value that you have in `Excel Sheet`: -

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("4256411411");
System.out.println(bd.doubleValue());

// If you are sure that's not a floating point number, then use
System.out.println(bd.longValue());
```

Prints: -

```
4.256411411E9  
4256411411
```

Comment: The input from excel sheet i am getting is in exponential form

Comment: @user1853173. Can't you fetch the value in string form and just convert it to `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @user1853173.. Don't store the fetched value in a `double` type. But in String type.

Comment: yeah i am able to convert that to BigDecimal but it is not giving the original value. please find the below code.

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("4.26E+09");
  long val = bd.longValue();

Comment: @user1853173.. Problem is you already don't have the exact value, so BigDecimal can't give you that value. It will only give the value which you pass to it.

Comment: @user1853173.. In what format the value is stored in Excel Sheet? And when you are fetching it, where are you storing it?

Comment: In the excel sheet i given "4256411411"value but while reading i am getting 4.62E+09. so i need to convert this valuwe

Comment: @user1853173 In that case you are extracting the value from excel incorrectly, you cannot not expect to parse an incorrect value to correct it.

Comment: @user1853173.. Show us the code where you are retrieving the value from Excel Sheet.

Comment: @user1853173.. Understand that we can't help you much until you show us some code.

Comment: In the above code for scancode i given the value as 4256411411 and formta of he cell is general if i save that one as number and read it will come first time correct value but when i just open the excel file and close then it is taking the format of the cell as general and displaying in exponential form

Comment: @user1853173.. What is the datatype of `scanCode`?

Comment: i mentioned above. the value is present in second cell for scancode and that is string type in java

Answer (score 5):

Try this definitely gona work
double value = 2.06E   //real 205809104.13
BigDecimal.valueOf(value)
work for me

Answer (score 4):

Before you read the value from excel sheet format your Column to number.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072561/how-can-i-read-numeric-strings-in-excel-cells-as-string-not-numbers-with-apach) may be helps to you

UPDATED

```
HSSFCell cellE1 = row1.getCell((short) 4);
cellE1.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
Double e1Val = cellE1.getNumericCellValue();
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(e1Val.toString());
long lonVal = bd.longValue();
System.out.println(lonVal);
```

Comment: You should do it pragmatically. Before read it you program should change it to number type. Also what is your excel reading API?

Comment: In java before reading the values from excel i need to change the format of the cell to number??

Comment: if you use Apache POI you could do this but I'm not aware of CSVReader.

Comment: I am not aware of Apache POI. Is this an API for reading excel??

Comment: Set your cell type to NUMERIC like this  before you read the value myCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);

Comment: i used this code.
HSSFCell cellE1 = row1.getCell((short) 4);
   cellE1.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);

   Double e1Val = cellE1.getNumericCellValue();but this is not working as expected

Comment: give me few mins I'll come back to you

Comment: what is your expected value?

Comment: this is the output "2.3432432423423E13" am getting for the "23432432423423". int he excel sheet format of the cell is general

Comment: Check my updated answer. I added few line to your code. try it and Let me know what happened.

Comment: Thank you so much. its working fine. i got the actual value what i expected.

Comment: Because others will get to know there is correct answer for same kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert easily with the following methods:

`Double.valueOf("9.78313E+2").longValue()` or

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("9.78313E+2");
long val = bd.longValue();
```

Assuming that the given number is in a String form.

Comment: The above code gives output as 4260000000. but this is not the original value for 4.26E+09.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use wrapper classes :

```
Double bd=new Double(4445566622);
System.out.println(bd.longValue());
```

Outputs `-4445566622`

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem when i only needed String Data that is "**1744949451**" but it give "**1.744949451E9**"
so this worked for me

```
          XSSFCell cell = cells.getCell(j);
          String value = cell.toString();
          if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            //cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            value = cell.getRawValue();
          }
          Log.i("LOG", value + " " + cell.getCellType());
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me:

```
Double bd = new Double(4445566622);
System.out.println(bd.longValue());
// Outputs -4445566622
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`Double value = double value ;
    Long longValue = value.longValue();  String strCellValue1 = new String(longValue.toString().format("%f",value).replaceAll("\\,?0*$", ""));`
```

declare a double value and convert to long
convert to string and formated to float the double value finally replace all the value like 123456789,0000 to 123456789

Answer (score -1):

Have to convert the cell into number format before reading the cell value. Below is the code snippet that is used to get the actual value that is in exponential format:

```
nextCell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
Double doubleValue = nextCell.getNumericCellValue();
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(doubleValue.toString());
long lonVal = bd.longValue();
String phoneNumber = Long.toString(lonVal).trim();
System.out.print("PhoneNumber " + phoneNumber);
```

[Blog](https://ankurjain26.blogspot.in/2017/10/convert-excel-exponential-number-in-java.html) has been wirtten to showcase the actual result.

Regards,
Ankur

Answer (score -1):

Try the following pattern:

```
Double dblValue = Double.parseDouble("1.99E+07");       
String str = String.format("%.2f", dblValue);
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
run:
19900000,00
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything that's not already better explained in [Brian Agnew's answer](/a/13563784/4850040).