# How do I print a double value without scientific notation using Java?

Tags: java, double

I want to print a double value in Java without exponential form.

```
double dexp = 12345678;
System.out.println("dexp: "+dexp);
```

It shows this E notation: `1.2345678E7`.

I want it to print it like this: `12345678`

What is the best way to prevent this?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You could use `printf()` with `%f`:

```
double dexp = 12345678;
System.out.printf("dexp: %f\n", dexp);
```

This will print `dexp: 12345678.000000`. If you don't want the fractional part, use

```
System.out.printf("dexp: %.0f\n", dexp);
```

0 in `%.0f` means 0 places in fractional part i.e no fractional part. If you want to print fractional part with desired number of decimal places then instead of 0 just provide the number like this `%.8f`. By default fractional part is printed up to 6 decimal places.

This uses the format specifier language explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

The default `toString()` format used in your original code is spelled out [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29).

Comment: but it showed `dexp: 12345681.000000` which is wrong value.And actually after then I want to display it on my web page where it display like this `1.2345678E7`.Is there anyway through which i can store it in any double like  `12345678` and any other way?

Comment: @despicable: You may be have been looking at the old, incomplete version of the answer. Try reloading the page. There should be a paragraph about `%.0f`.

Comment: @despicable you could store dexp as an int so you can easily use it both ways

Comment: IT ROUNDS OFF THE NUMBER

Comment: `%.0f` rounds off the number. Is there a way to just discarding the trailing zeros?

Answer (score 310):

### Java prevent E notation in a double:

Five different ways to convert a double to a normal number:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double myvalue = 0.00000021d;

        //Option 1 Print bare double.
        System.out.println(myvalue);

        //Option2, use decimalFormat.
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(8);
        System.out.println(df.format(myvalue));

        //Option 3, use printf.
        System.out.printf("%.9f", myvalue);
        System.out.println();

        //Option 4, convert toBigDecimal and ask for toPlainString().
        System.out.print(new BigDecimal(myvalue).toPlainString());
        System.out.println();

        //Option 5, String.format 
        System.out.println(String.format("%.12f", myvalue));
    }
}
```

This program prints:

```
2.1E-7
.00000021
0.000000210
0.000000210000000000000001085015324114868562332958390470594167709350585
0.000000210000
```

Which are all the same value.

Protip: If you are confused as to why those random digits appear beyond a certain threshold in the double value, this video explains: computerphile why does `0.1`+`0.2` equal `0.30000000000001`?

http://youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Comment: It just tells us how to print the double value. what if I want to return it as JSON?

Comment: I wrote: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");` `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);` `String str = df.format(dbl);` But when I pass **1234567890.0123456789** as the double value, the return value becomes **1,234,567,890.0123458**. Similarly, when I pass **12345678.0123456789**, it returns **12,345,678.01234568**. You can see the fractional precision is lost. But when I pass **12345678.899**, it returns **12,345,678.899**. This time the precision is retained. Why is this happening randomly? How can I make sure the precision remains correct always? Please help in sorting it out.

Answer (score 142):

**In short:**

If you want to get rid of trailing zeros and Locale problems, then you should use:

```
double myValue = 0.00000021d;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340); // 340 = DecimalFormat.DOUBLE_FRACTION_DIGITS

System.out.println(df.format(myValue)); // Output: 0.00000021
```

**Explanation:**

Why other answers did not suit me:

- `Double.toString()` or `System.out.println` or `FloatingDecimal.toJavaFormatString` uses scientific notations if double is less than 10^-3 or greater than or equal to 10^7
- By using `%f`, the default decimal precision is 6, otherwise you can hardcode it, but it results in extra zeros added if you have fewer decimals. Example:

  ```
  double myValue = 0.00000021d;
  String.format("%.12f", myvalue); // Output: 0.000000210000
  ```
- By using `setMaximumFractionDigits(0);` or `%.0f` you remove any decimal precision, which is fine for integers/longs, but not for double:

  ```
  double myValue = 0.00000021d;
  System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", myvalue)); // Output: 0
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
  System.out.println(df.format(myValue)); // Output: 0
  ```
- By using DecimalFormat, you are local dependent. In French locale, the decimal separator is a comma, not a point:

  ```
  double myValue = 0.00000021d;
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
  df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);
  System.out.println(df.format(myvalue)); // Output: 0,00000021
  ```

  Using the ENGLISH locale makes sure you get a point for decimal separator, wherever your program will run.

Why using 340 then for `setMaximumFractionDigits`?

Two reasons:

- `setMaximumFractionDigits` accepts an integer, but its implementation has a maximum digits allowed of `DecimalFormat.DOUBLE_FRACTION_DIGITS` which equals 340
- `Double.MIN_VALUE = 4.9E-324` so with 340 digits you are sure not to round your double and lose precision.

Comment: What is your opinion of `new BigDecimal(myvalue).toPlainString()` From the description at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()), it's not immediately obvious how it behaves when given different types of numbers, but it does eliminate scientific notation.

Comment: `new BigDecimal(0.00000021d).toPlainString()` output `0.0000002100000000000000010850153241148685623329583904705941677093505859375` which is not what you would expect ...

Comment: any idea how to use your answer in scala? probably a matter of appropriate imports but I'm new here.

Comment: ``BigDecimal.valueOf(0.00000021d).toPlainString()`` works as well (it uses the String constructor of BigDecimal that's why)

Comment: This answer doesn't work well for floats: `24.728352f` becomes `"24.728351593017578"`.

Comment: @JBE: This is still relevant in 2022. I wrote: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");` `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);` `String str = df.format(dbl);` But when I pass **1234567890.0123456789** as the double value, the return value becomes **1,234,567,890.0123458**. Similarly, when I pass **12345678.0123456789**, it returns **12,345,678.01234568**. You can see the fractional precision is lost. But when I pass **12345678.899**, it returns **12,345,678.899**. This time the precision is retained. Why is this happening randomly? How can I make sure the precision remains correct always?

Answer (score 32):

I've got another solution involving BigDecimal's toPlainString(), but this time using the String-constructor, which is recommended in the javadoc:

> this constructor is compatible with the values returned by Float.toString and Double.toString. This is generally the preferred way to convert a float or double into a BigDecimal, as it doesn't suffer from the unpredictability of the BigDecimal(double) constructor.

It looks like this in its shortest form:

```
return new BigDecimal(myDouble.toString()).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
```

NaN and infinite values have to be checked extra, so looks like this in its complete form:

```
public static String doubleToString(Double d) {
    if (d == null)
        return null;
    if (d.isNaN() || d.isInfinite())
        return d.toString();

    return new BigDecimal(d.toString()).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
}
```

This can also be copied/pasted to work nicely with Float.

For Java 7 and below, this results in "0.0" for any zero-valued Doubles, so you would need to add:

```
if (d.doubleValue() == 0)
    return "0";
```

Comment: I've read countless schemes to convert a double value to a String and this is the best: short, straightforward, configurable.

Comment: Why `d.doubleValue() == 0` instead of `d == 0`?

Comment: Because it avoids auto-unboxing, which I like better in that situation, but views may of course differ on this. If you're on java 8 (9 will probably be the same), you can leave out those 2 lines altogether.

Comment: Just tried with java 9, those 2 lines can be left out on 9 as well.

Answer (score 31):

You can try it with `DecimalFormat`. With this class you are very flexible in parsing your numbers.
You can exactly set the pattern you want to use.
In your case for example:

```
double test = 12345678;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
System.out.println(df.format(test)); //12345678
```

Comment: Accordingly, I wrote: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");` `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);` `String str = df.format(dbl);` But when I pass **1234567890.0123456789** as the double value, the return value becomes **1,234,567,890.0123458**. Similarly, when I pass **12345678.0123456789**, it returns **12,345,678.01234568**. You can see the fractional precision is lost. But when I pass **12345678.899**, it returns **12,345,678.899**. This time the precision is retained. Why is this happening randomly? How can I make sure the precision remains correct always? A little help, please.

Comment: Hello @priyamtheone, in order to answer this we need first to understand that the decimal numbers of primitive types like float/double are processed in a co-processor in the CPU called the FPU (Floating point unit). This unit holds the numbers in a completely different format called IEEE754 standard (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754.)
In this format there is one bit for sign, 11bits for exponent (double) and 52bit for the fraction or mantissa. The way of saving it gives a good precision up to 16 digits for double. So, as you can see - your example really stretches that case here.

Answer (score 9):

Java/Kotlin compiler converts any value greater than 9999999 (greater than or equal to 10 million) to scientific notation ie. **Epsilion notation**.

Ex: 12345678 is converted to 1.2345678E7

Use this code to avoid automatic conversion to scientific notation:

```
fun setTotalSalesValue(String total) {
        var valueWithoutEpsilon = total.toBigDecimal()
        /* Set the converted value to your android text view using setText() function */
        salesTextView.setText( valueWithoutEpsilon.toPlainString() )
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

This will work as long as your number is a whole number:

```
double dnexp = 12345678;
System.out.println("dexp: " + (long)dexp);
```

If the double variable has precision after the decimal point it will truncate it.

Comment: and as long as it fits into a `long` ...

Answer (score 5):

I needed to convert some double to currency values and found that most of the solutions were OK, but not for me.

The `DecimalFormat` was eventually the way for me, so here is what I've done:

```
   public String foo(double value) //Got here 6.743240136E7 or something..
    {
        DecimalFormat formatter;

        if(value - (int)value > 0.0)
            formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); // Here you can also deal with rounding if you wish..
        else
            formatter = new DecimalFormat("0");

        return formatter.format(value);
    }
```

As you can see, if the number is natural I get - say - 20000000 instead of 2E7 (etc.) - without any decimal point.

And if it's decimal, I get only two decimal digits.

Comment: I wrote: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");` `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);` `String str = df.format(dbl);` But when I pass **1234567890.0123456789** as the double value, the return value becomes **1,234,567,890.0123458**. Similarly, when I pass **12345678.0123456789**, it returns **12,345,678.01234568**. You can see the fractional precision is lost. But when I pass **12345678.899**, it returns **12,345,678.899**. This time the precision is retained. Why is this happening randomly? How can I make sure the precision remains correct always? A little help, please.

Answer (score 3):

I think everyone had the right idea, but all answers were not straightforward. 
I can see this being a very useful piece of code.  Here is a snippet of what will work:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.8f", EnterYourDoubleVariableHere));
```

the `".8"` is where you set the number of decimal places you would like to show.

I am using Eclipse and it worked no problem.

Hope this was helpful. I would appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 2):

The following code detects if the provided number is presented in scientific notation. If so it is represented in normal presentation with a maximum of '25' digits.

```
 static String convertFromScientificNotation(double number) {
    // Check if in scientific notation
    if (String.valueOf(number).toLowerCase().contains("e")) {
        System.out.println("The scientific notation number'"
                + number
                + "' detected, it will be converted to normal representation with 25 maximum fraction digits.");
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
        formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(25);
        return formatter.format(number);
    } else
        return String.valueOf(number);
}
```

Comment: I wrote: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");` `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);` `String str = df.format(dbl);` But when I pass **1234567890.0123456789** as the double value, the return value becomes **1,234,567,890.0123458**. Similarly, when I pass **12345678.0123456789**, it returns **12,345,678.01234568**. You can see the fractional precision is lost. But when I pass **12345678.899**, it returns **12,345,678.899**. This time the precision is retained. Why is this happening randomly? How can I make sure the precision remains correct always? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a tangent.... but if you need to put a numerical value as an integer (that is too big to be an integer) into a serializer (JSON, etc.) then you probably want "BigInterger"

Example:

value is a string - 7515904334

We need to represent it as a numerical in a Json message:

```
{
    "contact_phone":"800220-3333",
    "servicer_id":7515904334,
    "servicer_name":"SOME CORPORATION"
}
```

We can't print it or we'll get this:

```
{
    "contact_phone":"800220-3333",
    "servicer_id":"7515904334",
    "servicer_name":"SOME CORPORATION"
}
```

Adding the value to the node like this produces the desired outcome:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(Long.parseLong(value, 10))
```

I'm not sure this is really on-topic, but since this question was my top hit when I searched for my solution, I thought I would share here for the benefit of others, lie me, who search poorly. :D

Answer (score 2):

This will work not only for a whole numbers:

```
double dexp = 12345678.12345678;
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(dexp));
System.out.println("dexp: "+ bigDecimal.toPlainString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem in my production code when I was using it as a string input to a math.Eval() function which takes a string like  "x + 20 / 50"

I looked at hundreds of articles... In the end I went with this because of the speed. And because the Eval function was going to convert it back into its own number format eventually and math.Eval() didn't support the trailing E-07 that other methods returned, and anything over 5 dp was too much detail for my application anyway.

This is now used in production code for an application that has 1,000+ users...

```
double value = 0.0002111d;
String s = Double.toString(((int)(value * 100000.0d))/100000.0d); // Round to 5 dp

s display as:  0.00021
```

Answer (score 1):

use `String.format ("%.0f", number)`

> %.0f for zero decimal

```
String numSring = String.format ("%.0f", firstNumber);
System.out.println(numString);
```

Answer (score 0):

For integer values represented by a `double`, you can use this code, which is much faster than the other solutions.

```
public static String doubleToString(final double d) {
    // check for integer, also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9898613/868941 and
    // https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/math/DoubleMath.java
    if (isMathematicalInteger(d)) {
        return Long.toString((long)d);
    } else {
        // or use any of the solutions provided by others, this is the best
        DecimalFormat df = 
            new DecimalFormat("0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340); // 340 = DecimalFormat.DOUBLE_FRACTION_DIGITS
        return df.format(d);
    }
}

// Java 8+
public static boolean isMathematicalInteger(final double d) {
    return StrictMath.rint(d) == d && Double.isFinite(d);
}
```

Comment: This is still relevant in 2022. I wrote: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");` `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);` `String str = df.format(dbl);` But when I pass **1234567890.0123456789** as the double value, the return value becomes **1,234,567,890.0123458**. Similarly, when I pass **12345678.0123456789**, it returns **12,345,678.01234568**. You can see the fractional precision is lost. But when I pass **12345678.899**, it returns **12,345,678.899**. This time the precision is retained. Why is this happening randomly? How can I make sure the precision remains correct always? Help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
String str = String.format ("%.0f", yourDouble);

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. The output will be a String.

```
String.format("%.12f", myvalue);
```

Comment: THis adds extra 0 padding