# My calculator messes up when I use digits more than 8

Tags: java, android

I made up a calculator seeing a tutorial on youtube, and the code works perfectly fine when I use it with 4-5 digits. But when I use it with around 8 digits the result messes up. For example 200000000-200= 1.99998E7 Can someone please correct my code?

```
    package com.example.asd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Typeface font1, font2;

    TextView tv1;
    private EditText Scr; //textbox screen
    private float NumberBf; //Save screen before pressing button operation;
    private String Operation;
    private ButtonClickListener btnClick;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        font1=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "digits.ttf");
        Scr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Scr.setTypeface(font1);
        font2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "alexbrush.TTF");
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setTypeface(font2);
        Scr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Scr.setEnabled(false);
        btnClick = new ButtonClickListener();
        int idList[] = {R.id.button0,R.id.button7, R.id.button1, R.id.button8,R.id.button9,R.id.button4,
                R.id.button5,R.id.button6,R.id.button,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.buttonDot,
                R.id.buttonMul,R.id.buttonDiv,R.id.buttonAdd,R.id.buttonSub,R.id.buttonC,
                R.id.buttonEq, R.id.buttonSqrt, R.id.buttonsquare
        };

        for(int id:idList){
            View v = (View) findViewById(id);
            v.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void mMath(String str){
        NumberBf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString()); //save the screen
        Operation = str; //save operation
        Scr.setText("0"); //Clear screen
    }

    public void getKeyboard(String str){
        String ScrCurrent = Scr.getText().toString();
        if(ScrCurrent.equals("0"))
            ScrCurrent = "";
        ScrCurrent += str;
        Scr.setText(ScrCurrent);
    }

    public void mResult(){
        float NumAf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
        float result = 0;
        if(Operation.equals("+")){
            result = NumAf + NumberBf;
        }
        if(Operation.equals("-")){
            result = NumberBf - NumAf;
        }
        if(Operation.equals("*")){
            result = NumAf * NumberBf;
        }
        if(Operation.equals("/")){
            result = NumberBf / NumAf;
        }
        Scr.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }

    public void fnSqrt(){
        double Number = Double.parseDouble(Scr.getText().toString());
        Number = Math.sqrt(Number);
        Scr.setText(String.valueOf(Number));
    }

    public void fnSquare(){
        float Number1 = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
        Number1 = pow(Number1, 2);
        Scr.setText(String.valueOf(Number1));
    }

    //new class ButtonClickListener


    private float pow(float number1, int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return number1*number1;
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener{
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.buttonC: //Clear screen
                    Scr.setText("0");
                    NumberBf = 0;
                    Operation = "";
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonAdd: //function Add
                    mMath("+");
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonSub:
                    mMath("-");
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonMul:
                    mMath("*");
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonDiv:
                    mMath("/");
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonEq:
                    mResult();
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonSqrt:
                    fnSqrt();
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonsquare:
                    fnSquare();
                    break;
                default:
                    String numb = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
                    getKeyboard(numb);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java

Answer (score 4):

Are you concerned about the imprecision? Or the scientific notation?

`String.valueOf` has the same result as `Double.toString`, which has this statement in its specification:

> If m is less than 10^-3 or greater than or equal to 10^7, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let n be the unique integer such that 10^n ≤ m < 10^(n+1); then let a be the mathematically exact quotient of m and 10^n so that 1 ≤ a < 10. The magnitude is then represented as the integer part of a, as a single decimal digit, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by decimal digits representing the fractional part of a, followed by the letter 'E' ('\u0045'), followed by a representation of n as a decimal integer, as produced by the method Integer.toString(int).

Consider using `String.format("%.20d", value)` or something similar to gain more control over the stringification of a double.

Comment: Umm, thanks for answering. Sorry to say, I am a total noob, and what you answered made only a little sense to me. If the change that is required is a small one, can you please change it in my code and show me? Thank you very much

Comment: Change `Scr.setText(String.valueOf(result))` to `Scr.setText(String.format("%10d", result))` to show the number with no more than 10 characters. Change 10 to however many characters should be visible in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Using `float` as your datatype in a calculator app is never recommended do to its imprecise nature. If you change all of your variables to `double`, which as the names suggests has double the precision of a float, your results should no longer be slightly off.

Also, you can look into using `BigDecimal` or `DecimalFormat`. BigDecimal is a class that can handle many decimal places with significant accuracy. DecimalFormat will allow you to clean up the display of imprecise decimal numbers.

Comment: I will change it to double right now. :)

Comment: +1 for recommending BigDecimal

Comment: How do I use bigdecimal?

Comment: I mean, can you please show it where and how to implement it in my code?

Comment: BigDecimal can be constructed from a String. Therefore, you can use `BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Scr.getText().toString());` in places where you would create a float. The oracle docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html can give you some specific class methods to use for your calculations.