# How to Avoid Scientific Notation in Double?

Tags: android, double

Here is my simple code

```
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            double price = Double.parseDouble(ePrice.getText().toString());
            double percent = Double.parseDouble(ePercent.getText().toString());

            double priceValue = price * percent/100.0f;
            double percentValue = price - priceValue;

            moneyToGet.setText(String.valueOf(priceValue));
            moneyToPay.setText(String.valueOf(percentValue));

            moneyToGet.setText("" + priceValue);
            moneyToPay.setText("" + percentValue);

            // catch
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // write a message to users
            moneyToGet.setText("");
        }
    }

});
```

This is a simple code for Percentage Calculator.

What I want is to avoid the **Scientific Notation** in my Calculator cause I don't want to explain to user what is Scientific Notation.

**For example** if I want to calculate **100,000,000** and cut **50%** of it, it Should give me **50,000,000** which is giving me **5.0E7** And in my case this doesn't make any sense to the user. And of course I know both results are correct.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print double value without scientific notation using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java). You can write

```
moneyToGet.setText(String.format("%.0f", priceValue));
```

Comment: Note that if your number has a decimal part, it'll drop it.

Answer (score 8):

**You can try this DecimalFormat**

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat("############");
number.setText(decimalFormatter.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `BigDecimal`s instead of `double`s. That way you will have a more precise control over your calculation precision. Also you can get a non-scientific `String` using `BigDecimal.toPlainString()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat("##.############");
                    decimalFormatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
                    decimalFormatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(15);
```

This option will help you ##.## suffix 0 before decimal, otherwise output will be .000

```
 btc.setText(decimalFormatter.format(btcval));
```

use this for displaying content

Answer (score 0):

Use NumberFormater like

```
NumberFormat myformatter = new DecimalFormat("########");  

String result = myformatter.format(yourValue);
```