# android: calculate double percentage?

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate percentage. But it's giving me wrong result(2.78674E7).

Following's my code:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn_pre_payment;
    private EditText et_pre_payment;

    private double monthlyPayment;
    private double allPayment = 139337000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        btn_pre_payment = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_prepayment);
        et_pre_payment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_prepayment);

        btn_pre_payment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(et_pre_payment.getText().length() > 0){

                    float value = Float.valueOf(et_pre_payment.getText().toString());
                    if(value >= 10){

                        InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et_pre_payment.getApplicationWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);


                            **monthlyPayment = (allPayment / 100f) * value;
                            tvMonthlyPaymentH.setText(String.valueOf(monthlyPayment));
                            remainderPayment -= monthlyPayment;**

                        }

                    } else Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Low is 10%!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Enter value!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Why can't it calculate correct result? It gives me 2.78674E7. I want to calculate percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is given in scientific notation  you can try using

`String.format("%.0f", YourValue)`

to get correct value .

check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813631/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-in-double) question

Comment: Oh It's because format. I thought it's strange to be math wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your math is wrong.  It should be value/total*100, not value*total/100.

Comment: 20/100 *100 and 20 * (100/100)

Comment: No, it isn't.  Total is in the denominator in the correct version, not the numerator.  And 100 should be in the numerator, not the denominator.  Your version is backwards

Comment: @GreedRuler WHat you have isn't that.  Yours is the difference between (100/20)*100 and (20/100)*100  one is 500, the other is 20

Comment: (20/100) * 100 and 20 * (100/100) ?

Comment: It's still gives me wrong answer. 4.180110166102648E7, So it's not main issue.

Comment: @GreedRuler x/y != y/x.  Division is not commutative.  Your problem is either you're misreading your own math.  And given that, I have doubts you got it right the second time either.

Comment: value is my persentage