# wrong calculation with double

Tags: android

I am working on a simple app, actually my first attempt in Android.

**Expected result**

- I need the result to be shown in the English Language only, in case the mobile language is in Hindi for example.
- I want the number to be shown without the letter (E) when the number is long.

**Code**

```
protected void operation(char ope){
 double num1 = Double.parseDouble(txtNum1.getText().toString());
 double num2 = Double.parseDouble(txtNum2.getText().toString());
 double resultMulti = 0;
 switch (ope) {
   case '*':
     resultMulti = num1 * num2;
     long a3=(long)resultMulti;
     if (resultMulti-a3 <= 0)
        txtMultiResult.setText(a3 + "");
     else
        txtMultiResult.setText(String.format("%.2f",resultMulti));// without E but will be converted to Mobile Language

     // txtMultiResult.setText(resultMulti+""); // with E
     // txtMultiResult.setText(String.valueOf(resultMulti));// With E
     //  txtMultiResult.setText(Double.toString(resultMulti));// with E

     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(btnMulti.getWindowToken(),0);
     break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Avoid Scientific Notation in Double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813631/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-in-double)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Locale.ENGLISH` inside `String.format()`? As in like the following:

```
txtMultiResult.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", resultMulti));
```