# How can I stop Java from shortening large double?

Tags: java, numbers, double

Let's suppose we have the following code:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(100000000000.0));
```

Now the output to that is 1.0E11. But that is not what I want. (Looks bad on a highscore)
I want it to output exactly 100000000000.0. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @HotLicks Would be better if you have posted an answer showing how

Comment: Are you sure your high scores should be doubles in the first place? Even if fractional scores are allowed, I would be rather surprised to find that scoring 0.1 points and then 0.2 points was very slightly different from scoring 0.3 points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Format it appropriately. For example:

```
System.out.printf("%.1f", 1654621658874684.0);
```

Be aware that double is not infinitely precise. It has a precision of about 15 to 17 decimal digits. If you need floating-point numbers with arbitrary precision, use BigDecimal instead of double.

Or you could use String.format():

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", 1654621658874684.0d));
```

Comment: Thanks! That provided me with everything I needed, and added some additional useful information.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.printf("Score: %.0f\n", 1e5);` will print `100000`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this ...
[Quest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

You can use DecimalFormat to format your value for displaying

Answer (score 0):

For those kind of big numbers, I think you should use BigDecimal.