# Android multiplying double with int [java]

Tags: java, android

I have a double value a = 0.00059
and an Integer value which gets incremented and multiplied with the double value (say b = 1)

when I set the answer to the textview

```
//for b = 1
view.setText(((double)(a*b)));
```

the answer I get is " 5.9E-4 " however it should be 0.00059.

am I multiplying the values correctly.?

Comment: Try with view.setText(String.valueOf((double)(a*b)));

Comment: The value it gives is correct, but it's the scientific notation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print double value without scientific notation using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java) is what I suspect you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers provided, you can use a formatter:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
view.setText(formatter.format(a*b));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are multiplying them correctly.  The values `5.9E-4` and `0.00059` are equivalent, mathematically and programmatically.  The representation `5.9E-4` is like scientific notation, i.e. 5.9x10^(-4) is equivalent to 0.00059.

Answer (score 3):

You get the same value as you want to get, but formatted in a scientific notation. What you need to do is to explicitly convert it to String:

```
view.setText(String.format("%f", a*b));
```

And you could eventually specify the number of decimal places to print after the decimal separator in this way:

```
// displays two digits after the decimal separator
view.setText(String.format("%.2f", a*b));
```