# Convert Double to String Android

Tags: java, android, string, double

i try to save my String value `(50000000)` into Double format, while I'm trying to show it again in my `Edittext`, I can't to show it in normal format, and it show as `(5E+07)`, is there any way to convert from double format into String format?
I have try this way :

```
Double value_doble = 5E+07;
EditText.setText(String.valueOf(value_doble);
```

but its Still show as 5E+07, so my question how to convert from Double to String?

Comment: why do you convert that string into double?

Comment: because it Request from my User

Comment: how do you convert string to double?

Comment: @FlorescentTicker `Double value_doble =Double.parseDouble(txt.getText.toString());`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print double value without scientific notation using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(value_doble).toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Double value_doble = 5E+07;
       NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.#####");   
       String f = formatter.format(value_doble);   
       System.out.println(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you need use Formater 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

but the pattern should be look like this:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;


public class DoubleFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double valueD = 5E+07;
        NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#");
        System.out.println(format.format(valueD));
    }

}
```