# Why format changes while reading data from excel file using poi api java?

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel sheet, While reading the format changes like following

> 2 comes like 2.0, 1189736455 comes like 1.18973645E8  in Exponential
>   format..

Why this happens, can anybody please help..
Thanks in advance...

here is my sample code   Sheet_numUI and Sheet_numDB are the number of sheet form two files... Generally here I read from a file and compare with some value which I stored in a list and the result I store in another excel file... But while getting data from second file that is workBookUI (in my program) I'm not getting expected values...

the following are the files :  reader [image]
and output file is : [image]

```
   if(Sheet_numUI==Sheet_numDB){
            for(int i=0;i<Sheet_numUI;i++){
                Sheet_nameDB=workBookDB.getSheetAt(i).getSheetName();
                Sheet_nameUI=workBookUI.getSheetAt(i).getSheetName();
                ResultXLS_Reader =  new OMEGA_XLSX_Reader(file.getAbsolutePath());
                ResultXLS_Reader.addSheet1(Sheet_nameDB);
                counter=4;
                DBCol=readerDB.getColumnCount(Sheet_nameDB);
                DBRow=readerDB.getRowCount(Sheet_nameDB);

                UICol=readerUI.getColumnCount(Sheet_nameUI);
                UIRow=readerUI.getRowCount(Sheet_nameUI);
                for(int y=0;y<DBRow;y++){
                    for (int x=0;x<DBCol;x++){
                        if(y==0){
                            val=readerDB.getCellData(Sheet_nameDB, x, y+1);
                            ResultXLS_Reader.setCellDataStringColorLightGreen(Sheet_nameDB, x+1, y+1,val);
                        }else{
                            val=readerDB.getCellData(Sheet_nameDB, x, y+1);
                            ResultXLS_Reader.setCellData(Sheet_nameDB, x+1, y+1,val);
                            list.add(val);

                        }
                        System.out.println("List : "+ list);
                    }
                }
//              data insertion over
                compVal=(String) map.get(Sheet_nameDB);
                for(int k=0;k<=UIRow;k++){
                    for(int l=0;l<UICol;l++){
                        val=readerUI.getCellData(Sheet_nameUI, l, k);
                        if(val.equalsIgnoreCase(compVal)){

                            completeRow=readerUI.getRow(Sheet_nameUI, k-1);
                            for(Cell cell: completeRow){
                                list2.add(cell);
                            }
                            if(list2 != null && list2.size() > 0){
                            for(int m=0;m<list2.size();m++){

                                String val1=list.get(m).toString();
                                String val2=list2.get(m).toString();

                                if(val1.equalsIgnoreCase(val2)){
                                    ResultXLS_Reader.setCellDataColorLightGreen(Sheet_nameDB,m+1,counter, val1);

                                }else{
                                    ResultXLS_Reader.setCellDataColorRed(Sheet_nameDB, m+1,counter, val2);
                                }
                            }
                            counter=counter+1;
                        }
                            list2.clear();
                        }

                    }
                }
                list.clear();
                counter =0;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please provide more details, i.e. sample of code you use to read the values. Also where does it come misformatted, is that when you're trying to read the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the cell method .getNumericCellValue() which returns a double - a double will always print at least 1 decimal. As for the exponential format, that is just how large doubles print. See this question for how to deal with printing large doubles without scientific notation: [How to print double value without scientific notation using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Also, if your goal is printing the results back out into another spreadsheet with POI, you can create a cell style to format the numbers you put into a cell. For example:

```
DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
CellStyle number = workbook.createCellStyle();
number.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#,##0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function . You need to call this function for the expected value

```
public static String convertNumberToString(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    try {

        return new BigDecimal(obj.toString()).toBigInteger().toString();
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

you should be able to get the proper string