# Converting exponential into number in java

Tags: java

Please somebody help me.I m using JAVA
I am using double to store the number.
After calculation i am getting output as 1.38964527E+13 but i want the output as 13896452700000 in this format.somebody please tell me how to make this change.
I have already tried to converting it into integer or string.nothing works.
Thank you in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `NumberFormat`:

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#").format(yourLongNumber));
```

(You should not create a new format for each output, so reuse it when possible.)