# Wrong format of Double type with exponential in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

in my page jsp I have a double property ${ bean.property } but it display like this :

```
1.598E7
```

how can I make it to with out `E7` and replace it with 0 like  `15980000`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print double value without scientific notation using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Comment: not duplicate because i want display it in jsp.

Comment: its not 1.59 but 15980000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`formatNumber`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="5" value="${bean.property}" />
```

Comment: do you need more for display purpose ?

Comment: like what ? i try it without `maxFractionDigits="5"` and it works that i ask you.

Comment: it is non required attribute, so it will work without it as well with default behavior, if you don't want more digits in display you could control with this attribute (which is usually the case)

Comment: i got it now it's for To display the numbers on JSP with maximum number of digits after decimal point so i choose to put 2 instead of 5

Comment: ok you could refer to doc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html and play around with more attributes if required

Comment: thanks man for your help ... you can add it to your answer for more details.