# Double diplaying in Scientific Notation instead of normal value in JSTL(JSP). While the same value is displayed normal in JSON Format

Tags: java, spring, double, jstl, scientific-notation

I have Java object , which contains a property of double.

I am using Spring MVC. When attaching the Java Object (Model) to JSP page and rendering (ModelAndView) , It is displaying in scientific notation.

**1.1980598E7**

While, on the other hand, when returning the JSON object, double is displaying normally.

**11980598**

Please suggest. I want to display as normal value in both the cases.

Below didn't work for JSTL.

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
sampleDoubleValue =Double.valueOf(df2.format(sampleDoubleValue ));
```

Some one marked this question as Duplicate question. I would also like to know why It is working in JSON but not JSP. So please dont consider this as duplicate question unless until the previous question answers my question completely.

Comment: Of course not. You just threw away your carefully formatted string.

Comment: But, the same is returning as a normal double value in JSON. @shmosel

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: How should I make it work?

Comment: Print the result of `df2.format(sampleDoubleValue )`.

Comment: In JSP, I dont want to do any computations. So I am looking for a solution, where I can compute in Java only and just return to JSP for rendering.

Comment: So return the string to the JSP.

Comment: This serves my requirements. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568117/wrong-format-of-double-type-with-exponential-in-jsp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong format of Double type with exponential in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568117/wrong-format-of-double-type-with-exponential-in-jsp)