# convert String to Double in EditText

Tags: java, android, string, performance, double

I am making an android application. The user will enter a 11-15 digit in android `EditText` as I have to do some mathematical work on this no,  i need to convert it into double but so far this is not working well

how can i get the same string after parsing it into double

so far this is my code:

```
String Svalue="1101300045"
double Dvalue=Double.parseDouble(Svalue);
System.out.print("Dvalue: "+Dvalue);
Dvalue++; 
Svalue=Double.toString(Dvalue);
System.out.print("Svalue: "+Svalue)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Dvalue: 1.11013001045.E15 
Svalue: 1.11013001046.E15
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Dvalue: 1101300045
Svalue: 1101300046
```

Comment: Format `Svalue`. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: Please edit your que..it contains many errors like 》; on first line 》dvalue++ to Dvalue++ and 》when you again make Svalue to Dvalue check spelling

Comment: yeah thats not a big a deal.. people here can understand such notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format a `Double` you make use of the `NumberFormat` utility class.

```
    String Svalue = "1101300045";
    double Dvalue = Double.parseDouble(Svalue);

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
    System.out.println("Dvalue: " + nf.format(Dvalue));

    Dvalue++;
    Svalue = nf.format(Dvalue);
    System.out.println("Svalue: " + Svalue);
```

You can also format decimal values with rounding support like

```
    Svalue = "1101300045.98765";
    Dvalue = Double.parseDouble(Svalue);

    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    System.out.println("Dvalue: " + nf.format(Dvalue));
```

***Output :***

```
Dvalue: 1101300045
Svalue: 1101300046
Dvalue: 1101300045.99
```

Comment: Thank youu,it worked, although
 why are we using "setGroupingUsed"

Comment: With grouping enable your values will be formatted as `1,101,300,045.99` for example.

Comment: [`code`] Svalue = nf.format(Dvalue); is this removing the E notation from the Dvalue? #just asking for future reffrence thanx in advacne

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
double Dvalue = Double.parseDouble(name.getText().toString());
System.out.print("Dvalue: "+Dvalue );

Svalue=Double.toString(Dvalue);
System.out.print("Svalue: "+Svalue)

Comment: int Ivalue = Integer.parseInt(name.getText().toString()); System.out.print("Ivalue: "+Ivalue );

String Svalue=Integer.toString(Ivalue); System.out.print("Svalue:"+Svalue);

you can use calculation on integer. 
The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point
when you try to use String as 12.2345768 and then convert into double then it show you the correct value

Comment: noo int wont parse it ill be gone under exception.. please checck your answer before posting them

Comment: it is working fine
String S="1101300045";

int i=Integer.parseInt(S);
please check carefully 
System.out.print(i);

Comment: my dear, my number is too large to fit in an int which is 32 bits and only has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647..  i am not that dumb .. in my questio i have mentioned that my String will contain 11-15 char

Comment: i know this thing but i send the above code after successfully executed just try to run above code on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php
then check it

Comment: as per your request i executed my code in your site " and it returned me with numberexccetopn error"..

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered several times. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937683/1226020) answer provides several useful approaches.

Comment: Thanks ill check them out

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1: Using `Double.parseDouble`

`public static double parseDouble(String str) throws NumberFormatException`
It returns the double value represented by the string argument and throws following exceptions:

`NullPointerException` – if the specified `String` `str` is null.

`NumberFormatException` – if the string format is not valid.  For e.g. If the string is `122.20ab` this exception will be thrown.

```
String str="122.202";
Double var= Double.parseDouble(str);
```

Double variable var value would be `122.202` after conversion.

### Method 2: Using `Double.valueOf`

```
String str3="122.202";
Double var3= Double.valueOf(str3);
```

The value of `var3` would be `122.202`.

### Method 3: `Double` class constructor

```
String str2="122.202";
Double var2= new Double(str2);
```

`Double` class has a constructor which parses the passed `String` argument and returns a double value.

```
public Double(String s) throws NumberFormatException
```

Constructs a newly allocated `Double` object that represents the floating-point value of type double represented by the string.

Complete Example:

```
try{
   //Using parseDouble
   String str="122.202";
   Double var= Double.parseDouble(str);
   System.out.println(var);

   String str2="122.202";
   Double var2= new Double(str2);
   System.out.println(var2);

   //Using valueOf method
   String str3="122.202";
   Double var3= Double.valueOf(str3);
   System.out.println(var3);

}catch (NullPointerException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
 catch (NumberFormatException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Output:

```
122.202
122.202
122.202
```

---

As additional, here's how to get the text from `EditText`:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
String text = et.getText().toString();
```

[**Source**](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-convert-string-to-double-in-java/).

Comment: Whatever the content of your `String`, you are free to enter any value, whether it's a decimal value or not. So, just put the value you want into `EditText` (i.e. `1101300045`).

Comment: it wont work,in my answer i have already showed you the output of this scenario