# Convert KB to MB in java

Tags: java, double, decimal, exponential, exponent

I want to convert KB to MB but when the file size is very small, converting 
**result is exponential that as follows:**

very small file size:17.48 kb convert to 1.748E-5

**and converter code in java is as follows:**

```
List<Double> file_size = (List<Double>) doc.getFieldValue("file_size");
..
..
//According to google converting formula
file_size.set(0, file_size.get(0)*Math.pow(10.0, -6.0));
```

***and finally, i want to convert result(exponential) to double***

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print double value without scientific notation using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
double m = size/1024D
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use printf instead of println

Comment: It would probably aid the OP if you explained why that is

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java

Comment: @gurghet: Please consider *editing* your answer to include more detail as to why your proposed solution is correct.