# stop System.out from putting big and small numbers into standard form

Tags: java

when ever I put a big or small number through System.out.println() (in Java), it decides to convert something like 0.003897 to 3.897E-3 which is hard to read when going through my temporary-testing-debug-log-thing.

is there any way to keep it as 0.003897?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20937683/1343161

Answer (score 1):

Use DecimalFormat like: #.#######

Usage:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Either use:

```
System.out.println( String.format( "%.6f", 123.456789d )
```