# How to parse json having very long value for a key. See code snippet below

Tags: android, json

Hot to get exact value of key `"totalValue"` from the json mentioned below:
(Note: I tired `json.getdouble("totalValue")` but not getting the exact value of key `"totalValue"`

*Code Snippet:*

```
String jsonStrTemp="    {\n" +
        "        \"branchName\": \"CAG MUMBAI\",\n" +
        "        \"branchId\": \"51\",\n" +
        "        \"totalValue\": 177777783312648600000\n" +
        "      }";
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(jsonStrTemp);
    System.out.println("testDB jsonStr getLong : "+jsonObj.getLong("totalValue"));
    System.out.println("testDB jsonStr getDouble : "+jsonObj.getDouble("totalValue"));

} catch (JSONException e) {
    System.out.println("testDB JSONException");
}
```

*Output:*

```
System.out: testDB jsonStr getLong : 9223372036854775807 
System.out: testDB jsonStr getDouble : 1.777777833126486E20 
System.out: testDB jsonStr getString : 1.777777833126486E20
```

Comment: That is exponential notation. It is only printed that way. You do have the actual value.

Comment: @pravin Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @vucko : No, still struggling for for it.. but hope will solve it within few next hours...

Comment: What is the current problem? Maybe I can help. Did you notice my answer?

Comment: My problem was - I was not able to get very long/double value through json.getDouble(<StringName>) from the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

This: **1.777777833126486E20** represents the exponential notation of a number. That means the number is equals to the number preceding the letter **E** times 10^pow, where **pow** is the part of the number after the letter **E**. In this case pow=20, `number = 1.1.777777833126486 * 10^20.`

If you wish to format this any other way, refer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Comment: Thanks.Resolved the issue by doing following:-  String formatStr = String.format("%f", jsonValue);
        double lacCr = Double.parseDouble(formatStr); //where jsonValue= jsonObj.getDouble("totalValue")

Comment: Cool. I didn't want to write how to format since the question I linked clearly explained it. Consider accepting the answer to close the question. Thanks.