# input double number of 123456789 in test giving output of 1.23456789E8 using java.util.Scanner

Tags: java

input double number of 123456789 in test giving output of 1.23456789E8 using java.util.Scanner.  I input this in the console to test the output it should be giving me the output of 123456789.0 . I am stumped I have looked and looked as to why this is happening and just cannot find a solution for it.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;



/**
 * Created by Jeremy Roth on 10/6/2016  PRG420 Java I.
 * What we need calculated:
 * salary (constant at $55,000.00 per year)
 * totalSales  (total sales for the year)
 * commissionPercentRate from totalSales (percentage of earnings from totalSales)
 * salary + yearlyCommission
 * output: yearlyCommission
 * output: salary + yearlyCommission = earningYearTotal (earnings for the year total)
 *
 * This is just a simple assignment for console output but my question/goal is what further examples or changes might
 * be necessary to convert this into GUI output later in the course?
 */

public class Main {

    private static final double salary = 55000.00;  //my attempt and making this immutable not sure if I'm right
    public static final double commissionPercentRate = 0.12; //my attempt and making this immutable not sure
    public double totalSales = 0; //console input by user
    public double yearlyCommission = 0;
    //private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##");


    // (2) The instance variables are visible for all methods, constructors and block in the class. Normally,
    // it is recommended to make these variables private (access level). However, visibility for
    // subclasses can be given for these variables with the use of access modifiers.



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date date = new Date();

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Sales Commission Calculator!");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        System.out.println("Today is :" + date.toString());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        System.out.println("Make sure you have your sales documentation ready!");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        System.out.println("You will need your information handy to calculate your commissions!");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of your sales for the year: ");
        double number = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The amount you entered in sales for the year is: $" + number);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println("Your yearly salary is: $" + salary);



    }
}
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
Welcome to the Sales Commission Calculator!
Today is :Thu Oct 06 20:47:22 CDT 2016
Make sure you have your sales documentation ready!
You will need your information handy to calculate your commissions!
Enter the amount of your sales for the year: 
123456789
The amount you entered in sales for the year is: $1.23456789E8
Your yearly salary is: $55000.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: All it did was move the decimal point to the left 8 spaces. What is the problem?

Comment: Try `ystem.out.printf("The amount you entered in sales for the year is: $%.2f%n", number);`

Comment: I will give that a go! Thanks!

Comment: That works as a solution and it prints two decimal places.  I knew it had to be simple! I was thinking too hard on something so simple.  Again thanks!     Enter the amount of your sales for the year: 
123456789
The amount you entered in sales for the year is: $123456789.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I would not recommend using the `double` primitive type to represent money (`BigDecimal`, `int`, or `long` would be more appropriate), you can use `System.out.printf()` to avoid seeing the exponential form:

```
System.out.printf("The amount you entered in sales for the year is: $%.2f", number);
```

Comment: Thank you!  My next step was to code a second version using the BigDecimal and you are very right indeed.  It was a simpler mistake than I thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

1.23456789E8 is just scientific notation for 123456789

1.23456789E8 = 1.23456789 * 10^8 = 123456789

if you are saying you just want it to display as 123456789 in your output you can format it using printf instead of println:

System.out.printf("The amount you entered in sales for the year is: $%.0f\n", number);

credit to NPE for answering similar question on post:

[How to print double value without scientific notation using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)