# How to format a double so, that it will never show scientific notation?

Tags: java, string-formatting, number-formatting

I want to format a double so, that there's no scientific notation (the E letter) showing when I have a number larger than a million or so.

I have already formatted the double to have only two decimals.

as in

```
DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

but even with that, I'm seeing `10007999.00` as `1.001511661E7` on the screen.
I don't want to see it in that form (can't really think of why anyone would...)

How to format the double so, that it is showing as a normal number, not some letters in it. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't replicate for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java

Comment: This `DecimalFormat` should never format as scientific notation. Please post code to reproduce. My suspicion is that you are doing something like formatting then parsing to "change the format of `double`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 5-minute search on Google brought me here:
[How to print double value without scientific notation using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

This is what you want right?

Here's the same thing, but in a function:

```
public static String dNoScience(double d) {
    return String.format("%.0f\n", d);
}
```

Comment: Google wasn't my friend today. Thank you.