# I am unable to get the output as desired in java

Tags: java, number-formatting, scientific-notation

I am trying to read and print the value of double type using scanner class, but I am getting the output

My output
2.3534534534523453E11

Expected output
235345345345.234534

Comment: use `String.format("%.nf", floatValue);` where n is the number of digits you want to have in mantissa.

Comment: Should add Scanner class code so that somebody can help?

Comment: Share your codes, so that you get some help.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16098046/2814308) for more info on the subject. There are many more. Scanner is not related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same number what you seeing is called sintific notation you can use some thing like this to print it in the normal way

```
System.out.printf("dexp: %f\n", yournumbergoeshere);
```