# iReport pdf export shows incorrect values

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I use iReport to display chart. the value expression is type **Double** . the value is **0d** . even when I change the value to **0** it still shows **E-9** . the value must be zero.

[image: Graphe 1]

How to fixe it please?

Comment: It seems that `Double` values are printed with scientific notation. Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java and see whether you can alternate chart's behavior.

Comment: Thank you @localghost I will follow your link and revert.