# Exponential Value in JSP

Tags: java, string, decimalformat

I'm having trouble in displaying values in JSP, if entry with 4 decimal places has 3 zeroes before the last digit, it is displayed as 3.0E-4. Ex: 0.0004 entry displays 4.0E-4; 0.0001 displays 1.0E-4

Other entries with 4 decimal places has 1 or 2 zeroes before the last digit displays correctly. Ex: 0.0040 entry displays 0.0040 ,whole number entries displays correctly. Ex 1.0003 display 1.0003. It should display the actual values.

I used decimal formatter

```
DecimalFormat d4 = new DecimalFormat(",##0.0000");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print a double value without scientific notation using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Comment: Check the other answers to see multiple solution to the problem, one using `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: PS: provide a [mcve] of the usage you have in the JSP. Easier to validate the problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem by declaring the value from double to Big Decimal format.. Thank you guys..