# How to convert scientific notation number to regular decimal with places in kotlinlang

Tags: kotlin

I was trying to loop over a map. But it converted my decimal number with scientific notation.

```
    var myvar = mapOf("x" to 0.000001, "y" to 0.00000023)

    for((k, v) in myvar){
        println(v)
    }
//Its showing the result
1.0E-6
2.3E-7
```

How can I convert this in regular decimal with places
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print a double value without scientific notation using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Comment: System.out.printf(Locale.US, "%f\n", v)

Comment: I would like to suggest this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937683/3350224

Comment: See https://kotlintutor.com/questions/format-kotlin-string-templates/