# String to Double without exponential scientific in java

Tags: java

I need to parse String to Double, but with my current code i am getting exponential notation in it

```
String str = "10000000";
Double parsedString = Double.valueOf(str);
```

It's giving me 1.0E7.
I need output 10000000

Any help?

Comment: That is just how `Double` is stored, if you want to _print_ it with different values, format the printing output.  Something like `System.out.printf("%8.0f", parsedString);`. or using `DecimalFormat`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print a double value without scientific notation using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Comment: You can use "new BigDecimal(str)" if you don't want to use formatter.

Comment: @AshokPrajapati Thanks a lot. yes you are correct. I have tried with BigDecimal and it gives output that I am expecting. It also supports marshalling so can use it.

Comment: @vahdet nope, the 2 questions are different. I want to convert string to double and not want to print double

Comment: @Nexevis yup, you are correct that Double is stored in this way, it internally invokes parseDouble(String) and while parsing adds Exponential notation. I wanted somekind of logic to get things work. But anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can call a method for this.

```
Double parseStringToDouble = validate(str);
```

The definition of validate method will be

```
private Double validate(String s) {
  try{
    return Double.valueOf(s);
  } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
    // you can throw your custom exception here.
  }
}
```

With this you will not get any exponential notation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way `Double` numbers are displayed. If you want to display number in a different way you have to format it:

```
System.out.printf("%.0f", number);
```

Comment: I don't want to display double. My question is I have string and want to convert String to Double

Comment: And you did it... This "1.0E7" is the way of displaying 10000000.