# Convert a String to double without Exponential form

Tags: java

i would like to convert a string to double and keep it as it is ,for example i have :

719379705 instead of this 7.19379705E8

- is double type having the capacity to display 719379705 as it is and not in exponential form.

i use this method for conversion :

```
private double toDouble(String valeur) {
    if (valeur != null) {
        return Double.parseDouble(valeur);
    }
    return Double.NaN;
}
```

thanks

Comment: so what's your problem?

Comment: You have to differentiate between the double and its data structure and the visual representation of that data. You cannot change the first. but you can  change the second: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java

Comment: Both 719379705 and 7.19379705E8 are the **same** value, just different presentation.

Answer (score 5):

The value being returned is a valid double, and the `E` denotes exponential. You do not have to worry about what is being returned inside a double as long as it is a valid double value.

If you need a formatted double value, and not for the computation, I'd suggest you to rather stick to the `String`.

Even after that, if you just don't like a double value with an exponential, you can rather use the BigDecimal.

```
return BigDecimal.valueOf(valeur);
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: **Just a Note:** While I believe that `BigDecimal` is the correct way of representation of numbers, it has its own limitation in terms of speed.

Comment: but this  returns BigDecimal.valueOf(valeur); returns a BigDecimal .and me i want a double

Comment: @Arezki , the precision that you are looking is out of `double` capacity.

Comment: @VishwaRatna Double has sufficient precision for 719379705