# How to remove E notation from Double value

Tags: java

Good Day,

I'm experiencing about `E` value from `double` field I get from my database. Is there any method on how I remove/convert the `E` from the field value to become `double` variable.

Example value I get from the database field value:

> 5.7377159E7

Comment: How do you print/view and retrieve this value? Please share some code if possible. This question is pretty vague as it is right now

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java  ?

Comment: The linked-to question resolves the issue, but please be aware that you can't "remove E from a double". All you can do is *present* (a.k.a. format) the number in a different format. Doing that won't change anything about how the number is stored.

Comment: Just to add to what Joachim said, you can't "remove E from a double" because double doesn't have E. Double is just a binary number. It is up to the formater to display that number with E or not.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a decimal formatter as shown below

```
               DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
                df.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);
                 System.out.print(df.format("your_var_with_E"));
```

you can set the max number of decimal places by `setMaximumFractionDigits`