# Convert string to double without scientific notation

Tags: java, string, double

I have searched the internet but I could not find any solution (maybe, I've searched badly).
I want to convert the `String` `"108595000.5"` to a `double` and I have used these methods:

```
Double.parseDouble("108595000.5");
Double.valueOf("108595000.5");
```

Unfortunately, both of them return `1.08595E8`.
How can I convert this `String` to `double` without problem?

Comment: `1.08595E8'` is a correct representation of 108595000.5 number, just written in scientific notation.

Comment: Whats the issue in output ? double will return that only

Comment: If you are caring about output, use a `BigDecimal`... It will hold the correct `double` but can easily be printed in different notations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print a double value without scientific notation using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Comment: It's hard to wrap your head around it but a `double` doesn't "hold a scientific notation" or any notation at all. It represents a number. How that number is printed depends on how you print it.

Comment: I want to do mathematical operations on it so that I get into trouble. I want the real number

Comment: You are confusing presentation (printing the value) with the actual value of the `double` variable.

Comment: Which *mathematical operations* are you planning to do with that number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The methods you have used do not return `1.08595E8`**, instead, they return the number and what you are complaining about is the representation of that number in the console (or as a `String`).

However, you can specify how to output a `double`yourself with a specified formatting, see this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "108595000.5";
    // use a BigDecimal to parse the value
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    // choose your desired output:
    // either the String representation of a double (undesired)
    System.out.println("double:\t\t\t\t\t" + bd.doubleValue());
    // or an engineering String
    System.out.println("engineering:\t\t\t\t" + bd.toEngineeringString());
    // or a plain String (might look equal to the engineering String)
    System.out.println("plain:\t\t\t\t\t" + bd.toPlainString());
    // or you specify an amount of decimals plus a rounding mode yourself
    System.out.println("rounded with fix decimal places:\t" 
                        + bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
}
```

```
double:                             1.085950005E8
engineering:                        108595000.5
plain:                              108595000.5
rounded with fix decimal places:    108595000.50
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
value = new BigDecimal(yourString);
doubleValue = value.doubleValue();
```

if you want the **exact** value.

If you want 2 numbers after `","`

```
double a = yourDouble; 
System.out.printf("%.2f",a)
```