# How do I convert String to Float value without scientific notation using java?

Tags: java, floating-point

I want to convert String to a float value in Java without exponential form.

```
String value = "108595000";
System.out.println(Float.valueOf(value));
```

It shows this E notation: `1.08595E8.`

I want it to print it like this: `108595000.0`

What is the best way to prevent this?

Comment: https://javadevnotes.com/java-float-to-string-without-exponential-scientific-notation

Comment: Pls check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.out.printf("%.1f\n", value);`. The `.1` modifier to `%f` tells the formatter to use one decimal.

The answers to [How do I print a double value without scientific notation using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java) have a lot more details on formatting floating point numbers in java.