# Is there a better way handle maths calculations with doubles?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am building a simple inventory and sales app, so i wrote a profit calculation method in android to get the profits from all products as **total profit** and display it in TextView on the app. The values are in double so I wrote this method below to get the total profit but the output is a bit weird, it show's something like "2.45116E7" or "1.22558E7" and so on as it changes each time I run the app but has same format as the total profit. So I added Log.d to trace the outputs inside of the method and I realized that the method does get the profit values from each product and adds them up as the **total profit** but as soon as the **total profit** reaches 10,000,000 or above it changes to that output. Please I need help to understand what is wrong and possible solutions. See the method below with the screenshot of the Log.d outputs.

```
private double getStoreProfits() {
    for (Product product : products) {
        Log.d("Profit", String.valueOf(product.getProfit()));
        totalProfit += product.getProfit();
        Log.d("Total Profits", String.valueOf(totalProfit));
    }
    return totalProfit;
}
```

The output:

[image: Screenshot of the Log.d outputs]

Comment: I'd suggest using `BigDecimal` instead of `double` to start with, for currency operations. (Or compute everything in integers using BigInteger.)

Comment: do you understand that `E` is a specific notation in math ? is that part of your question ?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, I tried to use BigDecimal but Firebase (where I stored the data) throws an exception that it does not support BigDecimals, as its a business app, i wanted to use doubles or BidDecimals but since Firebase doesn't support that any other options?

Comment: If you use [System.out.printf](https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf#2-float-and-double-formatting), you can specify the width.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I do, but I just couldn't interpret it in this context, can you help and my question is how do i make the actual digits of my calculation show up instead of that expression?

Comment: @Botahamec but i want to set the value to a textview in my android app, System.out.printf won't do that on android app, or will it?

Comment: System.out.format("%.0f",profit);  Where profit is your value. This will print the full value with no zeros after the decimal point. For more information check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: @osebidev You should use [String.format](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format) then

Comment: @Appu okay I will check that out now

Comment: @Botahamec Thanks, i will try it out

Comment: If Firebase storage is one of the requirements, please edit your question to indicate that. There's no mention of it at the moment. (But you can use `BigDecimal` and store the result as a string.)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `String.valueOf(var)` with `String.format("%.2f", var)`.

This will give you all of the digits before the decimal point, followed by two digits after the decimal.

---

Of course, as Jon said, it would be a bit better in this case to use a BigDecimal. You can either convert it into a float or a double and use the method I already described (using `floatValue()` or `doubleValue()`) or you can use the `toPlainString()` method.

Comment: Thanks a million! That fixed it! Please can you point me to resources to under this and other related concepts better?

Comment: For anyone with this issue, this question has more details on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java