# Why a double division is returning a very wrong value?

Tags: java, double, precision

this code below is return a very strange result. It should return 0.0008, but is return 8.202154101077051E-4. Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
    double d1 = 0.0099;
    double d2 = 12.0700;
    double d3 = d1/d2;
    System.out.println(d3);
```

Comment: The output is indeed about 0.0008, [just in a different format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Comment: Format it if you don't like it. See `String.format`

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation**

> It should return 0.0008

It does.

"E" is a format for numbers that are either very big or very close to 0. If an E(value) stands behind a number, that basically means "take this number and multiply it by 10 ^ value".

If you take *8.202154101077051 x 10 ^ -4*, you will get *0.0008202154101077051*, which is approximatly *0.0008*.

**Solution**

How you can format numbers when printing them out is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937683) stackoverflow answer.