# Values of excel field is getting 3.0E9 where I need 3000000000 when trying to parse

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i have an excel to upload which has a column material id.That column contains alphanumeric values,But when i am trying to upload this file value the uploaded column in the jsp page is taking an unexpected E and also taking decimal of that number i am using apache POI to parse the excel.Here i have done so far

```
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                boolean isValidentry=true;
                System.out.println("Row number =" + (i+1));
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                CategoryObject categoryObject = new CategoryObject();
                categoryObject.setCode("");
                if(row.getCell(0)!=null && !"".equals(row.getCell(0).toString().trim())){       //Part Number
                    System.out.println("Get Cell 0 >>>>" +row.getCell(0).toString());
                    categoryObject.setCode(row.getCell(0).toString().trim());
```

[image]

The problem is that I'm getting `3.0E9` where I need `3000000000`.

categoryObject.setCode is taken as String field.This column is responsible for the material id.

Comment: You do not even say how you upload ! And is the problem in parsing the file, or in displaying in JSP ?

Comment: i have problem in getting the value which i upload to the jsp

Comment: can i prevent this ?? please help

Comment: You must first write a good question with relevant infos. Read (or carefully read again [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with elements on how you upload the file and how you access to it. I really cannot understand what happens with so few informations.

Comment: i am sorry for my unclear question.actauly the problem is that when i am trying to upload a value form the cell for ex 3000000000 the parsing is done as 3.0E9 for it.This is the problem.....

Comment: Ok, so I understand the problem is with the parsing done with Apache POI. Unfortunately I do not use it, and won't be able to help you :-( But I've proposed you an edit to your post. Feel free to edit it again if what I wrote is not exactly what you would have said.

Comment: use cell.getRawValue() for numeric type to get string : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563747/p/58442764

Answer (score 2):

Numbers in Excel are (except for a few edge cases) stored as floating point numbers. Large floating point numbers in Java, when formatted as a string, are printed in Scientific notation

Assuming what you really wanted was "give me a string that looks like what Excel shows for this cell", then *do not* call cell.toString(). This will not give you what you want in most cases

Instead, you need to use the [DataFormatter class](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html), which provides methods which read the Excel format rules applied to a cell, then re-creates (as best it can) those in Java

Your code should be:

```
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
for (Row row : sheet) {
     int rowNumber = row.getRowNum() + 1;
     System.out.println("Row number =" + rowNumber);
     CategoryObject categoryObject = new CategoryObject();
     categoryObject.setCode("");

     Cell cell = row.getcell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
     if(cell!=null) {
          String cellValue = fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
          if (! cellValue.trim().isEmpty()) {
             System.out.println("Get Cell 0 >>>>" + cellValue);
             categoryObject.setCode(cellValue);
          }
     }
 }
```

You may notice I've also fixed a bunch of other stuff as well....!

Answer (score 1):

use `BigDecimal` to prevent E notation from number

```
BigDecimal bDec = new BigDecimal("3.0E9");
System.out.println(bDec.toPlainString());
```

output:

```
3000000000
```

[running example](http://ideone.com/5MHgXH)

Comment: Or don't do silly double to string conversions in the first place... (The OP is basically calling toString on a double, hence getting scientific notation to start with)