# Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell “Poi”

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to consume data from a spreadsheet in Excel, but always of this error, already tried formatting the worksheet to text and number and still the error persists.

I saw a person using it resolved `cell.setCellType ( Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING ) ;` but I do not know where I fit this passage in my code.

```
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.name("j_username"));
WebElement searchbox2 = driver.findElement(By.name("j_password"));         

try {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\paulo.xls")); 
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    for (int i=1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
        String j_username = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        String j_password = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

        searchbox.sendKeys(j_username);
        searchbox2.sendKeys(j_password);
        searchbox.submit();  

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    workbook.close();
    file.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    fnfe.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Can you place full stacktrace error message?

Comment: What about `sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).toString()`?

Comment: @Abdull Your comment did more than the official answer :) Solved my problem

Comment: try cell.getRawValue() if you need string form numeric type : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563747

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Formatter will work fine in this case.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(workbookName);
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
String val = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col));
list.add(val);   //Adding value to list
```

Comment: this thing doesn't work for me though, the out put of it something like: SUM(I38+D39+F39-G39-H39)

Comment: @SGaber, you need to provide a formula evaluator as a second argument to the `formatCellValue` method, then it correctly formats even the formulas.

Answer (score 58):

```
    Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
    cell.setCellType ( Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING );
    String j_username = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, as have been said in comments, despite this works it isn't correct method of retrieving data from an Excel's cell.

According to the manual [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29):

> If what you want to do is get a String value for your numeric cell,
>   stop!. This is not the way to do it. Instead, for fetching the string
>   value of a numeric or boolean or date cell, use DataFormatter instead.

And according to the [DataFormatter API](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)

> DataFormatter contains methods for formatting the value stored in an
>   Cell. **This can be useful for reports and GUI presentations when you
>   need to display data exactly as it appears in Excel.** Supported formats
>   include currency, SSN, percentages, decimals, dates, phone numbers,
>   zip codes, etc.

So, right way to show numeric cell's value is as following:

```
 DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); //creating formatter using the default locale
 Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
 String j_username = formatter.formatCellValue(cell); //Returns the formatted value of a cell as a String regardless of the cell type.
```

Comment: for (int i=1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
cell.setCellType ( Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING );
String j_username = cell.getStringCellValue(); ?!?!

Comment: made three erros   Type mismatch: cannot convert from HSSFCell to Table.Cell
CELL_TYPE_STRING cannot be resolved or is not a field
The method getStringCellValue() is undefined for the type Table.Cell

Comment: there is only numbers in the spreadsheet 89550536100002595717

Comment: Don't do this! The [POI javadocs are very clear](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29) on this not being the right way!

Comment: @Gagravarr, you're right. I didn't know about this, will fix my answer later.

Comment: this thing doesn't work for me though, the out put of it something like: SUM(I38+D39+F39-G39-H39)

Comment: This fails for cells which have formulas.

Comment: @saran3h, read comments to the accepted answer, they might help you.

Answer (score 14):

As explained in the [Apache POI Javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29), you *should not* use `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)` to get the string value of a numeric cell, as you'll loose all the formatting

Instead, as the [javadocs explain](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29), you should use [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)

What DataFormatter does is take the floating point value representing the cell is stored in the file, along with the formatting rules applied to it, and returns you a string that look like it the cell does in Excel.

So, if you're after a String of the cell, looking much as you had it looking in Excel, just do:

```
 // Create a formatter, do this once
 DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US);

 .....

 for (int i=1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        Row r = sheet.getRow(i);
        if (r == null) { 
           // empty row, skip
        } else {
           String j_username = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0));
           String j_password =  formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(1));

           // Use these
        }
 }
```

The formatter will return String cells as-is, and for Numeric cells will apply the formatting rules on the style to the number of the cell

Comment: this thing doesn't work for me though, the out put of it something like: SUM(I38+D39+F39-G39-H39)

Answer (score 10):

**Before** reading the string value of the cell, You can set the type of the cell first:

```
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
String cellStringValue = cell.getStringCellValue()
```

Hint:

- Now, [Apache POI JavaDocs quite clearly state that you shouldn't do this!](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29)
- The suggested solution: to use [`DataFormatter`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)

More details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7100727/1824361

Answer (score 7):

Using the `DataFormatter` this issue is resolved. Thanks to "Gagravarr" for the initial post.

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

String empno = formatter.formatCellValue(cell0);
```

Comment: this thing doesn't work for me though, the out put of it something like: SUM(I38+D39+F39-G39-H39)

Answer (score 4):

```
CellType cell = row.getCell(j).getCellTypeEnum();

switch(cell) {
    case NUMERIC:
        intVal = row.getCell(j).getNumericCellValue();
        System.out.print(intVal);
        break;
    case STRING:
        stringVal = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        System.out.print(stringVal);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Helper method for different cell types:

```
private static String returnStringValue(Cell cell) {
    CellType cellType = cell.getCellType();

    switch (cellType) {
        case NUMERIC -> {
            double doubleVal = cell.getNumericCellValue();
            if (doubleVal == (int) doubleVal) {
                int value = Double.valueOf(doubleVal).intValue();
                return String.valueOf(value);
            } else {
                return String.valueOf(doubleVal);
            }
        }
        case STRING -> {
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        }
        case ERROR -> {
            return String.valueOf(cell.getErrorCellValue());
        }
        case BLANK -> {
            return "";
        }
        case FORMULA -> {
            return cell.getCellFormula();
        }
        case BOOLEAN -> {
            return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        }
    }
    return "error decoding string value of the cell";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use that code it definitely works and I modified it.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
//import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {

            Class forName = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = null;
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tables", "root", "root");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement pstm = null;
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\a1.xls");
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
            Workbook workbook;
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fs);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row;
            for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i);
                String name = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                String add = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

                int  contact = (int) row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();

                String email = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();

                String sql = "INSERT INTO employee (name, address, contactNo, email) VALUES('" + name + "','" + add + "'," + contact + ",'" + email + "')";
                pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstm.execute();
                System.out.println("Import rows " + i);
            }
            con.commit();
            pstm.close();
            con.close();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: most probably it happen if you not add libraries files like 1) dom4j-1.6.jar 2) xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar 3) poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar 4) poi-ooxml-3.9.jar 5) poi-3.10-FINAL.jar

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the other method to solve the Error: "Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell “Poi”"

Go to the Excel Sheet. Drag and Select the Numerics which you are importing Data from the Excel sheet. Go to Format > Number > Then Select "Plain Text" Then Export as .xlsx. Now Try to Run the Script

Hope works Fine...!

[Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell “Poi”.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njKzP.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are processing in rows with cellIterator....then this worked for me ....

```
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();   
  while(cellIterator.hasNext())
  {                         
        cell = cellIterator.next();
        String val = "";            
        switch(cell.getCellType()) 
        {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                val = String.valueOf(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                break;
        }
    .....
    .....
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class B3PassingExcelDataBase {


    @Test()
    //Import the data::row start at 3 and column at 1: 
    public static void imortingData () throws IOException {

        FileInputStream  file=new         FileInputStream("/Users/Downloads/Book2.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook book=new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet=book.getSheet("Sheet1");

        int rowNum=sheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println(rowNum);

        //get the row and value and assigned to variable to use in application
        for (int r=3;r<rowNum;r++) {

            // Rows stays same but column num changes and this is for only one person. It iterate for other.
             XSSFRow currentRow=sheet.getRow(r);

             String fName=currentRow.getCell(1).toString();
             String lName=currentRow.getCell(2).toString();
             String phone=currentRow.getCell(3).toString();
             String email=currentRow.getCell(4).toString()

               //passing the data
                yogen.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys(fName);    ;
                yogen.findElement(By.name("lastName")).sendKeys(lName); ;
                yogen.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys(phone);    ;

        }

        yogen.close();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `cell.setCellType ( Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING );` inside the loop, so it would treat the cell as per your requirement.

Following would be the code:

```
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.name("j_username"));
WebElement searchbox2 = driver.findElement(By.name("j_password"));         

try {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\paulo.xls")); 
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    for (int i=1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
        // Row will be iterated and Cell will be 0 and 1 as per the example:   
        row.getCell(0).setCellType(CellType.STRING); // set Cell Type as String
        row.getCell(1).setCellType(CellType.STRING); // set Cell Type as String

        String j_username = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        String j_password = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

        searchbox.sendKeys(j_username);
        searchbox2.sendKeys(j_password);
        searchbox.submit();  

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    workbook.close();
    file.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    fnfe.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.name("j_username"));
WebElement searchbox2 = driver.findElement(By.name("j_password"));         


try {

      FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\paulo.xls")); 
      HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

      HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    for (int i=1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){

            HSSFCell j_username = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0)
            HSSFCell j_password = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0)

            //Setting the Cell type as String
            j_username.setCellType(j_username.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
            j_password.setCellType(j_password.CELL_TYPE_STRING)

            searchbox.sendKeys(j_username.toString());
            searchbox2.sendKeys(j_password.toString());


            searchbox.submit();       

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }

      workbook.close();
      file.close();

     } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
      fnfe.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: As explained [in the Apache POI javadocs, you *should not* use setCellType to get the string value, it looses formatting](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<SupplierSubmittedDataMapperModel> convertExcelToList(String NAME){

    List<SupplierSubmittedDataMapperModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(NAME));
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(2);
        
        int rowNumber = 2;
          Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
          while(iterator.hasNext()) {
              Row row=iterator.next();
              
              
              Iterator<Cell> cells = row.iterator();
              int cid = 0;
              SupplierSubmittedDataMapperModel sp = new SupplierSubmittedDataMapperModel();
             
              while(cells.hasNext()) {
                  Cell cell = cells.next();
                  String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell.getRow().getCell(cid));
                  
                  switch(cid) {
                  case 0:
                      sp.setSectorType(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 1:
                      sp.setPlatformFamily(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      sp.setT1Supplier(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 3:
                      sp.setT2Supplier(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 4:
                      sp.setDistribotor(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 5:
                      sp.setT2PartCodeAtT1(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 6:
                      sp.setT2PartNumber(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 7:
                      sp.setLoA(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 8:
                      sp.setMultiSource(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 9:
                      sp.setQtyUsage(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 10:
                      sp.setDataType(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 11:
                      sp.setWeek22(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 12:
                      sp.setWeek23(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 13:
                      sp.setWeek23(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 14:
                      sp.setWeek24(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 15:
                      sp.setWeek25(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 16:
                      sp.setWeek26(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 17:
                      sp.setWeek27(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 18:
                      sp.setWeek28(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 19:
                      sp.setWeek29(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 20:
                      sp.setWeek30(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 21:
                      sp.setWeek31(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 22:
                      sp.setWeek32(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 23:
                      sp.setWeek33(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 24:
                      sp.setWeek34(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 25:
                      sp.setWeek35(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 26:
                      sp.setWeek36(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 27:
                      sp.setWeek37(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 28:
                      sp.setWeek38(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 29:
                      sp.setWeek39(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 30:
                      sp.setWeek40(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 31:
                      sp.setWeek41(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 32:
                      sp.setWeek42(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 33:
                      sp.setWeek43(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 34:
                      sp.setWeek44(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 35:
                      sp.setWeek45(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 36:
                      sp.setWeek46(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 37:
                      sp.setWeek47(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 38:
                      sp.setWeek48(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 39:
                      sp.setWeek49(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 40:
                      sp.setWeek50(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 41:
                      sp.setWeek51(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 42:
                      sp.setWeek52(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 43:
                      sp.setYear2023(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 44:
                      sp.setYear2024(cellValue);
                      break;
                  case 45:
                      sp.setYear2059(cellValue);
                      break;
                  default :
                      break;
                      
                  
                  }
                  
                  cid++;
                  
              }
              list.add(sp);
             System.out.println(sp);
               }
          
          workbook.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
        
        e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    return list;

}
```