# How to store excel numeric as string

Tags: java, excel

How can i set numeric number from excel to string type? as i want to show 0001 instead of 1 in system. Below are part of the detect excel cell type function. How should i modify it ?

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                value = dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
            } 
            else 
            {
                double value2 = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                if( Math.floor(value2) == value2 ) 
                {
                    int value3 = (int)value2;
                    value = ""+value3;
                }else{
                    value = String.valueOf(value2);
                }
            }
            break;
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            value = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:     
            if(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()==HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
            {
                double value2 = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                if( Math.floor(value2) == value2 ) 
                {
                    int value3 = (int)value2;
                    value = ""+value3;
                }else{
                    value = String.valueOf(value2);
                }                                       
            }else if(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()==HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                value = cell.getStringCellValue();
            }   
            break;      
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:   
            value = "";
            break;                      
        }   
    }
```

Comment: When you say "store excel numeric as string", do you actually mean "get cell value as text, formatted as Excel displays it"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell “Poi”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125465/cannot-get-a-text-value-from-a-numeric-cell-poi)

Answer (score 0):

Thilo gave the easiest way to do this,

```
String.format("%04d", 1);
```

Use [LongValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/LongValidator.html) to achieve the same by third party library.

```
LongValidator longValidator = new LongValidator();
String result = longValidator.format(1, "0000");
```

Comment: Or just `String.format("%04d", 1);` No need for external libraries.

Comment: The way i store my value to database, pstmt2.setString(16,(String)VrtSub.elementAt(16));

Comment: I failed to set this.. error on console... pstmt2.setString(16,String.format("%04d",vrtSub.elementAt(16)));

Comment: what is the exact result of the statement, pstmt2.setString(16,(String)VrtSub.elementAt(16));

Comment: i system out VrtSub = 2 supposely 0002.

Comment: what is the meaning of 16 in the setString