# Convert Phone number from double to integer

Tags: java, type-conversion, apache-poi

I am taking phone number from excel, using Apache POI.

```
System.out.println(
    "---------->" + cell.getNumericCellValue() + "--" + (int) cell.getNumericCellValue()
);

sel.setContactno(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
```

Output:

```
---------->8.902305623E9--2147483647
```

Exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell
```

How can I get the phone number properly?

Comment: why would a phone number be a numeric cell value?

Comment: The code you've posted is using `getNumericCellValue`. The exception suggests you're using `getStringCellValue`

Comment: Formatter might be a good place to start with excel file: take a look at this thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125465/cannot-get-a-text-value-from-a-numeric-cell-poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125465/cannot-get-a-text-value-from-a-numeric-cell-poi)

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException - if the cell type returned by
>   getCellType() is CellType.STRING

Most likely `cell.getNumericCellValue()` seems not to contain double. Please verify your excel data.

Edit:
I think the phone number should not be just a single entity in the first place. It can be composed of local code, country code etc. which can contain special characters like `+`. And thus it definitely should not be numeric. This composition should provide the desired flexibility. But it completely depends on your/op requirements.

Comment: Would it be generally more flexible or better practice to get the phone number as a String? Given that they often contain non-numeric characters such as `( ) -`, it would seem to me to be the more robust option.

Comment: @AustinSchäfer I think the phone number should not be just a single entity in the first place. It can be composed of local code, coutry code etc. which can contain special characters like `+`. This composition  should provide the desired flexibility. But it completely depends on the op's requirements.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Thanks for the quick answer! :)