# Type mismatch: cannot convert from CellType to int

Tags: apache-poi

I am developing an automation testing code with the following error:

> ```
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from CellType to int.
> ```

Please what can I do?

```
public static String cellToString(HSSFCell cell) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int type;
        Object result;
        type = cell.getCellType();

        switch (type) {

        case 0 : // numeric value in Excel
            result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
            break;
        case 1 : //String value in Excel
            result = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("No support for this of cell");
        }
        return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`CellType`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html) is an `enum`, not an int. The type of your `type` variable should be `CellType` and your switch should look like this:

```java
CellType type = cell.getCellType();
switch (type) {
    case CellType.NUMERIC : // numeric value in Excel
        result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        break;
    case CellType.STRING : //String value in Excel
        result = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("No support for this of cell");
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use `Enum#ordinal()`, which returns an ordinal integer of the enum value, but the example above is much preferable.

EDIT: Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30125586/5362510) about how to get cell value as string using `Formatter` instead of switch.