# Exponents in java

Tags: java, bigdecimal, exponent

Are there any built in java methods where I can convert this `"1.00E-7"` to `"0.0000001"`? I am using `BigDecimal` as datatype by the way. 
I am really stuck in here. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `1.00E-7` and `0.0000001` are numerically equal. Do you mean changing the `String` representation? You should also include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting exponential value in java to a number format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563747/converting-exponential-value-in-java-to-a-number-format)

Comment: @prasad that question does have multiple answers, but none are accepted and each answer has a comment from OP saying the desired results were not achieved. Not saying it isn't a possible duplicate or that this question isn't a duplicate of another SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    BigDecimal bigD = new BigDecimal("1.00E-7"); 
    System.out.println(bigD.toPlainString());
```

Comment: Oh..yea my apologies yea the answer is not correct. I have not read the question clearly.

Comment: Nope. You're right there! Thanks a lot. That saved my day :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `BigDecimal#toPlainString()`, per the documentation:

> [`toPlainString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()) - Returns a string representation of this `BigDecimal` without an exponent field.

[BigDecimal's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) lists three `to*String()` methods: The regular `toString()` method uses scientific notation (`1.00E-7)`, while `toEngineeringString()` uses engineering notation (`100E-9`) and `toPlainString()` uses no notation (`0.000000100`).

Comment: Yes Jonny you are right . I posted almost the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigDecimal#toPlainString()`