# JSONObject returned Double is not correct

Tags: android, json, double

I am trying to do a Cryptocurrency application which you can see the coins and their volume, low, high, last price, etc...

I am getting data from bittrex public api, but there is a problem with returned double elements

Ex:
when I look at the data in browser it is: `"Last":0.00004665`. But when
returned data to my app: `last = 4.665E-5`

How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: What is datatype of variable in pojo class

Comment: it is Double Last;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 Double.parseDouble("4.665E-5");
```

or

```
BigDecimal.valueOf("4.665E-5")
```

also check this :
   [Converting exponential value in java to a number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563747/converting-exponential-value-in-java-to-a-number-format)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, My Logs here;
Last Value Double: 5.6394E-4 , 
Last Value String: 5.6394E-4 , 
Last Value parse Double: 5.6394E-4