# BigDecimal and Exponential

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm trying to read the following value from an Excel file cell:

```
19,000,000.00
19,000,000.10
19,000,000.01
19,000,000.101
```

What I see in the Excel file are also those values.

However, my output respectively, when using `cell.getNumericValue()`:

```
1.9E+7
19,000,000.1
19,000,000.01
19,000,000.101
```

The conversion to the exponential values makes it hard to manipulate and obtain all the information I need from the value, because when calling the `.scale()` and `.precision()` methods, the value is completely off. (the exponential value in question gives me precision: 2; scale: -6 )

How do I make it so that I get what I see instead of the conversion? My end-goal, basically, is to ensure the length of the value does not exceed my settings (eg. Numeric(15, 3) )

I've tried:

```
Double.parseDouble()
BigDecimal.valueOf().doubleValue()
BigDecimal.valueOf().floatValue()
```

But everything keeps returning me back the exponential value.

### Edit

Due to request, portion of the code I'm doing, modified as to not show the whole thing and clutter:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

Object theObject = new Object();

Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
while (cellIterator.hasNext() && !hasError) {
   Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
   theColumnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();

  (switch statement omitted)
    numericValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    //numericValue will return values like 1.9E+7, 19000000.10
    // 19000000.01, 19000000.101
    // afaik, the return type is Double

    theObject.setAmount( BigDecimal.valueOf(numericValue) );
    //SetAmount function expects a BigDecimal input, hence the use


   /*
   Additional checking for length and precision here to try and catch and 
   log it. Put after and not before because so long as it's a valid value (ie. 
   not String), it should still go in.
   */

}
```

Comment: Note that `1.9E+7` is more of a text representation and I'd not use this for any checks or calculations unless the formatting is relevant. Otherwise shouldn't `19,000,000.101` and `19000000.101` have the same length? So what you need to do is check the values against _numeric_ boundaries, e.g.  `x > BigDecimal.valueOf("999999999999.999")` for a max value.

Comment: "But everything keeps returning me back the exponential value" - well it's returning a `double` value (or a `float` value). How that value is then converted *into a string* is an entirely separate matter. It sounds like really you just want `BigDecimal` without any conversion to `float` or `double`...

Comment: @JonSkeet While writing this question, I did wonder for a while whether the output is because it's part of a ```System.out```, but as mentioned, my ```.scale()``` and ```.precision()``` does not correspond with the value Im expecting, but in fact matches the exponential value. Basically, what I want is the actual value, not it converted to exponential value.

Comment: You can refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563747/converting-exponential-value-in-java-to-a-number-format

Comment: @Thomas The other values are more of additional examples. The most important one is the ```19000000.00``` value, which returns as ```1.9E+7```. I dont want this; I want the ```19000000.00``` value.

Comment: "what I want is the actual value" - the `BigDecimal` you get _is_ the value, `scale` and `precision` are more for other purposes and describe the internal representation of the value (i.e. `1000` could be represented as `value 1 + scale -3`, `value 10 + scale  -2` etc. - note the JavaDoc on `scale()`). Just work with the `BigDecimal` directly and the internal representation shouldn't matter).

Comment: You can refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563747/converting-exponential-value-in-java-to-a-number-format

Comment: @Venkatesh I originally added a PS in my OP to indicate that I've seen a few other threads before posting as none of their answers fit. That link was one of them; the top 2 most voted answers didnt fit my need.

Comment: I don't think your question is complete. You need to include the way you're creating the BigDecimal, and the way that you're comparing the BigDecimal and why you consider the results incorrect.

Comment: `1.9E7` is not the value. It is the result of some conversion to `String` which you haven't shown. You need to investigate `java.text.DecimalFormat`.

Comment: "// afaik, the return type is Double" You're assigning it to a variable, `numericValue` you should absolutely include the type. "//numericValue will return values like 1.9E+7, 19000000.10 " doubles don't work like that.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid the BigDecimal constructor with a `double` as floating point has no precision (scale). From a String the BigDecimal can determine the precision (scale -2 below).

```
BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal("19000000.00");
```

So one should not get double values from Excel.

Then for text presentation without scientific exponent notation:

```
System.out.println(n.toPlainString());
```

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, you should not do numerical constraint checks based on a text representation of a number.

If I remember correctly `Numberic(15,3)` basically means "15 digits, 3 of which are decimal places". This means you'd have the following constraints:

- min value: -999,999,999,999.999
- max value:  999,999,999,999.999
- max 3 decimal places

To check this you could do the following:

```
//construct the boundary values once and cache them
BigDecimal max = new BigDecimal("999999999999.999");
BigDecimal min = max.negate();

//get the value and strip trailing zeros to get `x.01` instead of `x.01000` etc.
BigDecimal value = cell.getNumericValue().stripTrailingZeros();

//check validity
boolean valid = min.compareTo(value) < 0 &&  //value not smaller than min which would mean more digits
                max.compareTo(value) > 0 &&  //value not larger than max which would mean more digits
                value.scale() <= 3; //scale <= 3, i.e. 3 decimal digits at most
```

Note on `scale()`: a negative value basically defines the number of zeros that would be added to the internally stored unscaled integer value, e.g. value = 123 and scale = -5 would actually mean "123 + 5 zeros, i.e. 12,300,000". A negative scale thus also implies that there are no fraction digits while a positive scale would indicate the number of fraction digits ("value = 123 and scale 2" would mean "move the decimal point 2 places to the left" so the actual value would be 1.23 - which means 2 fraction digits).

Comment: @user16320675 true and since scale should only be negative for integers this means there are no decimal digits in this case. Will correct it.