# Apache POI : How to format numeric cell values

Tags: apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.9 for XLS/XLSX file processing.

In the XLS sheet, there is a column with numeric value like "3000053406".

When I read it with POI with..

```
cell.getNumericCellValue()
```

It gives me value like "3.00E+08". This create huge problem in my application.

How  can I set the number formatting while reading data in Apcahe POI ?

There is a way that I know is to set the column as "text" type. But I want to know if there is any other way at Apache POI side while reading the data. OR can we format it by using simple java DecimalFormatter ?

Answer (score 3):

This one comes up very often....

Picking [one of my past answers to an almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7100727/685641)

> What you want to do is use the [DataFormatter class](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). You pass this a cell, and it does its best to return you a string containing what Excel would show you for that cell. If you pass it a string cell, you'll get the string back. If you pass it a numeric cell with formatting rules applied, it will format the number based on them and give you the string back.
>
> For your case, I'd assume that the numeric cells have an integer formatting rule applied to them. If you ask DataFormatter to format those cells, it'll give you back a string with the integer string in it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here I am little but confused with How to set the format in DataFormatter class. AS per my understanding, I want only numbers in resule withot floating point precision, So I need to set the format to ########. Am I right ? ..please confirm

Comment: Can you please provide some small stub kind of thing for better understanding. I tried with DataFormatter but I  can not understand How to set the format in DataFormatter class. Here I am using xls and xlsx formats so.. it is required to use HSSFDataFormatter ? and cellStyle.setDataFotmat(short) is asking for short value. How can I retrieve that short value ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to set anything - it fetches the formatting rules that were applied in Excel to the cell, and uses those to format the number

Comment: @Gagravarr can you provide a simple example where "it fetches the formatting rules that were applied in Excel to the cell"?

Comment: @onepotato Try it! Or look at the source to see... If it doesn't work correctly, you'll need to ask a new question about that

Answer (score 1):

Problem can be strictly Java-related, not POI related, too.
Since your call returns a double,

`double val = cell.getNumericCellValue();`

You may want to get this

`DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
 int fractionalDigits = 2; // say 2
 df.setMaximumFractionDigits(fractionalDigits);
 double val = df.format(val);`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a BigDecimal with the double value from the numeric cell and then using the

> BigDecimal.toPlainString()

function to convert it to a plain string and then storing it back to the same cell after erasing the value solved the whole problem of exponential representation of numeric values.

The below code solved the issue for me.

```
    Double dnum = cellContent.getNumericCellValue();
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(dnum);
    System.out.println(bd.toPlainString());
    cellContent.setBlank();
    cellContent.setCellValue(bd.toPlainString());
    System.out.println(cellContent.getStringCellValue());
```

Answer (score -2):

`long varA = new Double(cellB1.getNumericCellValue()).longValue();` 
This will bring the exact value in variable  `varA`.