# Converting double with value greater than 10^7 to string in java

Tags: java, string, excel, double, apache-poi

I am trying to read excel using apache poi(version 3.11). There is this cell containg value 30066069. I have converted the cell type to text in excel. However when I am trying to read it in java, the cellType comes out to be `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` and by using the following snippet of code

```
String cellValue = Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
```

my cellValue becomes 3.0066069E7. The documentations says the following about `toString()` method:

> If m is less than 10-3 or greater than or equal to 107, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let n be the unique integer such that 10n ≤ m < 10n+1; then let a be the mathematically exact quotient of m and 10n so that 1 ≤ a < 10. The magnitude is then represented as the integer part of a, as a single decimal digit, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by decimal digits representing the fractional part of a, followed by the letter 'E' >>('\u0045'), followed by a representation of n as a decimal integer, as produced by the method

Is there any way I can read the cell as 30066069.

Comment: Use String.format() and give a format specifier to get the digits of precision you need.

Comment: look at the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079796/apache-poi-how-to-format-numeric-cell-values

Comment: @Gene Thanks. This worked. cellValue = String.format("%.0f", cell.getNumericCellValue());