# How to get value as it is from excel in POI

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am fetching value from excel using below code :

```
if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC || cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA ){

          String cellText  = String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
}
```

In excel I have diff. kind of values like

- 100.0
- 5,000
- 15,000

Some values are with `decimal point` where some are with `comma (,)`. As I wanted rounded value of decimal , I am converting it to integer but now same line of code not working for value which has comma. I want value as it is from excel when it has `comma` but for now it returns me `5000`

**Note :** Cell type is numeric set in excel.

Comment: You do realize that the `comma` is used as thousand separator? If you want to change that, you will have to change the OS settings (I believe)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - Actually after fetching value from excel I am inserting into one website where there is dropdown and in dropdown values are with comma for thousand so if excel does not return me with comma , my xpath get failed when I insert.

Comment: Did you try using `DataFormatter` ? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079796/apache-poi-how-to-format-numeric-cell-values)

Comment: It looks like `DataFormatter` is your best bet. I thought about changing the cell type to `String`, but checking in excel, i realized that it doesn't work

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - can you give me simple example with dataformatter related to my question? it would help me a lot.

Comment: `String str = new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell)` should do the trick. If `DataFormatter` can't parse the text, then you will need to add an extra format. [Read the docs for more info](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)

Comment: @HelpingHands can you share a dummy data with same formatting , so that I can provide a specific solution/help

Comment: @mohitsharma - you mean to share excel. I shared data in question I think.

Comment: @HelpingHands For values with comma you can using value.contains(","). Then Split the String and covert it to non-comma integer.

Comment: @mohitsharma - You are correct but when I get value from excel it comes like 5000 without comma, but in actual value in excel is 5,000 (with comma).