# Apache-POI field formatting

Tags: apache-poi

How do I specify if the information is numeric?  The it.MOPID field is suppose to be a numeric field but comes through as text.  Any thoughts to this?

```
cellMOPID.setCellValue(it.MOPID)
cellStartDate.setCellValue("" + it.SOM)
```

Comment: If your cell data type is predefined to be integer you can create cell with numeric type like `XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(0).createCell(0, Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);` 

or you can use `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);` for existing cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the cell type, something like:
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html
[Apache POI - get number as integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557495/apache-poi-get-number-as-integer)