# How to get the original string value of a cell that looks numeric but isn't?

Tags: apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI 5.2.0 to read XLSX files and am having an issue with reading some string values that are getting parsed incorrectly as numeric.

The value that is visible in Excel (without the quotes) is a comma separated list of numbers, for instance: "1111,2222,3333"

When i parse the spreadsheet with POI, the cell type is inevitably NUMERIC.

I've tried:

- Setting the CellType to STRING and calling getStringCellValue() or getRichStringCellValue() (returns "111122223333")
- Using the DataFormatter (returns "111,122,223,333")

How can i get the value as it is shown in Excel? ("1111,2222,3333")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache POI - get number as integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557495/apache-poi-get-number-as-integer) --  The question is the opposite direction, but the accepted answer should work for what you are trying to do ..

Comment: tried `'1111,2222,3333` ? (a single opening quote... which formats any cell "input" to text ..in excel at least)

Comment: @Zak that would be the DataFormatter solution which i tried and it just reformats the number and i lose where the original commas are, so i lose the information.

Comment: @xerx593 Changing the excel file at the source is not an option in my case.

Comment: I can't even recreate your Excel source data. If I enter the string `1111,2222,3333` into Excel, then - yes - Excel interprets it as a number - but it gets displayed in a "Number" cell, the commas are removed (it is stored as `111122223333`) and the _display_ format is `111,122,223,333` (using thousands separators) - which is different from what you are seeing. The only way I can display a value as `1111,2222,3333` in Excel is by forcing the cell to be a "Text" format - and then I can also extract it as that exact same text using POI `cell.getStringCellValue()`...

Comment: If you open the file in Excel where the computer is set to a different locale, eg US-English does it show with the same as in Apache POI with the comma every 3 not 4 numbers?