# Using XSSFWorkBook to read excel alters the cell numbers accuracy

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using the `package org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc;` package to read in an excel file and it is changing the accuracy of the numbers being read from excel.

I have an instance in which if I have 1.11 or 2.22 or 4.44 in a cell then the XSSFWorkbook returns a 1.110000000001, 2.220000000002 and so on. Has anyone got an idea what is going on?

Comment: Which function did you use to get cell value? `cell.get...Value()`

Comment: I am in the process of doing some debugging and after call Workbook.create(inputStream) I inspect the rows from the sheet and can see that the number contained in the rows contains the extraneous zeroes

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/7100727/624003 and then http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the exact problem as you described here in the past, and I believe the problem stems from Java's precision problem with `double`. In my workaround, I converted and formatted the `double` value into `String` before setting the string value into the cell.