# Number as it is from excel file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI (version 3.9) framework for dealing with excel files, i.e. reading excel file.

I am having trouble with number types. User can write a number in excel file with comma or dot as decimal separator, i.e. 12.34 or 12,34, for various reasons.

Now, I would like to get that value as it is (i.e. if it is 12.34, then I would like to get 12.34, or if it is 12,34, then I would like to get 12,34), but instead POI Cell preliminary gives me a double with dot as decimal separator. 
So, if a cell value was 12,34, POI Cell would give double of value 12.34.

This behaviour is not what I would like to be. I would like to get the value that was entered (12,34).

How to avoid/solve this?

I have searched Stackoverflow for similar problems and tried to use solution given in thread [How can I read numeric strings in Excel cells as string (not numbers) with Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072561/how-can-i-read-numeric-strings-in-excel-cells-as-string-not-numbers-with-apach) and also tried using alternative `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter` class, and it works, but it does not work when the the value is 12,34 and type of cell is Number defined in Excel file itself.

Comment: The data you are looking for isn't stored in the cell value. The value is just a number. You'll have to look at the cell formatting and then format the number as a string yourself.

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you for your reply. I didn't emphasize that while reading an excel file (which user provided) I need to do some validation. And I would formatted it, if only I would get a string and not an already modified double. Do you have any comments on this?

Comment: If you are validating the numbers, I would suggest that you might have more luck converting your validation string into a number to compare with the value in the cell. There is no information stored in the spreadsheet about the decimal/thousands separator. That is based on the locale set in the application or OS and is display-only - it is not stored at all. So you will have to manually format the number as a String.

Comment: Thank you Gary for this valuable information :) Just, it is quite unbelievable that this framework can't just give value as it is written in the cell. I can't understand it, because I'm sure they know it. Anyway, thanks a lot again!

Comment: Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit for answering it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are validating the numbers, I would suggest that you might have more luck converting your validation string into a number to compare with the value in the cell. There is no information stored in the spreadsheet about the decimal/thousands separator. That is based on the locale set in the application or OS and is display-only - it is not stored at all. So you will have to manually format the number as a String.