# Getting wrong numeric values from Excels first column

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I read Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx) with Apache-poi 3.8. When I try to get numeric value from cell at 0 column index, I get wrong numberic value.

For example my table looks like this

```
+-----------+---------+---------+
| Header1   | Header2 | Header3 |
+-----------+---------+---------+
| 123456789 | AA      | BB      |
|     99999 | CC      | DD      |
+-----------+---------+---------+
```

I begin to read on Row index 1 and Cell Index 0. It should returns `123456789` but it returns wrong value `13`. Next columns are correct even if it's numeric value. If the first cell contains string it returns correct value as well. Row 2 Cell 0 reads like 14 and next columns are correct.

The number I get from first column is somehow related to amount of rows in sheet, If I have 6 rows, it starts to return `16,17,18,19,20`. It should not have to be related with other frameworks but I use `myfaces tomahawk` and `jsf 1.2` for upload my Excel file.

```
public String getCellStr(final int x, final int y) {
    String cellValue = "";
    try {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(x);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(y);
        if (row == null || (row != null && cell == null)) {
            cellValue = "";
        } else {
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                cellValue = cell.toString();
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    cellValue = DateUtils.date2String(cell.getDateCellValue());
                } else {
                    Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    Long longValue = value.longValue();
                    cellValue = longValue.toString();
                }
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                cellValue = new String(new Boolean(
                                  cell.getBooleanCellValue()).toString());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                cellValue = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return cellValue;
    }
    return cellValue;
}
```

Comment: DO NOT use new String(...), it is not necessary toString already return a String object.

Comment: Also, i do not think that excel indexing starts at zero, rather at one. So try fetching the column with index 1.

Comment: Hi, first set the cell format as String before you read it and then you read it .. it can be set as cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); then read using your code cell.getNumericCellValue();

Comment: @Lawrence It starts on zero, i tried it.

Comment: @user1763507 I tried your way too but no difference.

Comment: use this and try ....new Double(cell.getNumericCellValue())

Comment: @user1763507 same result. I tried many ways how to read a cell value. Only way how can i get number from first column is to put apostrophe before the number on Excel level. But it's not a solution.

Comment: Its strange... working fine on my end and giving the expected result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read numeric strings in Excel cells as string (not numbers) with Apache POI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072561/how-can-i-read-numeric-strings-in-excel-cells-as-string-not-numbers-with-apach)

Comment: @Sankumarsingh I think it that is problem in my configuration or file is corrupted through my uploading (myfaces tomahawk).

Comment: @Gagravarr No it's not, I tried their solution, but It's quite different problem. I have problem only with first column and only when there are numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find my mistake. This code was responsible for the strange behaviour. Apparently I cannot cast cell to other type and cast it back without destroying value.

```
int cellType = cell.getCellType();
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
String val = cell.getStringCellValue();
cell.setCellType(cellType);
```