# How to assert decimal Excel value with the web value using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: c#, excel, selenium-webdriver, decimal, data-driven

The value mentioned in the Excel file is `21.650` and same value is presented on the page. But when script executes, it reads Excel value as `21.65` and my assert condition becomes false.

```
List<string> rowValue = new List<string> { };
var ExcelFilePath = "D:\\testexcel.xlsx";

Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application(ExcelFilePath);
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath);
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;

for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    rowValue.Add(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());

    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id(weight_field));
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

    string weight = driver.FindElement(By.Id(weight_field)).Text;

    if (mpuid == i)
    {  
        Assert.AreEqual(weight,rowValue[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(" Expected Value: " + rowValue[0] + " is equal to Actual Value: " + weight);
        break;
    }

    rowValue.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Excel file, change your cell Category as Text.

Answer (score 0):

Use  DataFormatter class as suggested in answer for[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072561/how-can-i-read-numeric-strings-in-excel-cells-as-string-not-numbers-with-apach/7100727#7100727). As this will return the exact text from excel file as it is displayed.