# How to write a very large number in xlsx via apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to write to an excel cell a very large numbers(>`91430000000000000000`)
The issue is that max value for cell is `9143018315613270000`, and all values which is larger - would be replaced by max value. 
This issue will simply resolved by hands if an apostrophe is added to an number, for example `'9143018315313276189`
But how to the same trick via apache POI? I have follow code:

```
    attrId.setCellValue(new XSSFRichTextString('\'' + value.getId().toString()));
```

But it doesn't work:

[image: Example]

Here the first row haven't any apostrophe at all, second one is written by hands and it is the result I'm looking for. Third is a result of my code. I also tried to use setCellValue which takes double and String, both of them doesn't help me ether.

So, here goes the question: How to write in excel a very large numbers via apache POI?

Comment: Set cell type to **text** using `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)` and write **number as text**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the cell style first

```
DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
CellStyle testStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
testStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));
String bigNumber = "9143018315313276189";
row.createCell(40).setCellStyle(testStyle);
row.getCell(40).setCellValue(bigNumber);
```

Comment: Yeah, that works for me. It's look a little bit tricky for me. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the Cell type and see what happens. Or if you have already set that then please post your code so that others look at it.

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

Please refer to the question in here for details on how to set string value to cell [How can I read numeric strings in Excel cells as string (not numbers) with Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072561/how-can-i-read-numeric-strings-in-excel-cells-as-string-not-numbers-with-apach)

I did the following sample and worked for me (poi-3.1.3)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;


public class WriteToExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue("91430183153132761893333");

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = 
                    new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test_stackoverflow\\new.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, the result is the same as in cell number 3. If I edit via hands the value without any changing(just point on value via mouse) - I gain the result I expect to, but is there any automatic way?

Comment: When I clicked in the cell, I saw the effect. I guess addition of the style as shown by @hughs is the way forward.