# Read Date and all other cells data as string from excel using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jxl

I am working on a requirement where i need to validate xlsx file records and display validations to end user.I am using Apache POI and The problem is when a row contains a date cell like(01/31/2015) during parsing it is going inside numeric cell type switch case and giving some unexpected value(42005 like that).

I cant use getDateCellValue since I am converting xls to csv and doing different validations there. Hence irrespective of xls formula/format, I should get the value exactly entered by the user for my requirement not only for date but for all other types ( as of now I found issue with only with date strings). I have tried below code and please update me with any other solutions since I am not sure that below code will work fine for all scenarios.

```
if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){


     if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
           DataFormatter format= new DataFormatter();
           FormulaEvaluator fe = Workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
           String str= format.formatCellValue(cell, fe);
           return str;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use `DataFormatter` for all cases, and let it do all the work for you?

Comment: If I use date format it will convert the actual cell data according to format specified. I want to have actual data(01/31/2015) which will be handled later in my parser module. First I need to read the xlsx file as it is with out any formatting which modifies the actual data

Comment: Please note that Excel actually always uses a format for displaying stuff, e.g. it stores dates as double internally, not "exactly what the user entered" and displays the date via a format, using a default format if no special one is set. So the DataFormatter will usually be the closest what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Kiran, i believe you can get the info regarding any cell format by using this `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);` before reading the cell content.

This answer was answered already, but for numeric formats:
[How can I read numeric strings in Excel cells as string (not numbers) with Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072561/how-can-i-read-numeric-strings-in-excel-cells-as-string-not-numbers-with-apach)

Comment: .I have tied that but its not working.even after setting cell type as string ,The method cell.getStingValue() returning "42005" for the value 01/31/2015 in the excel sheet cell

Comment: Is it possible to modify the file Before running your code?,
If this is possible, it would be very simple to create a macro to run this file before processing so you can have all data inside the excel file as string.