# Excel Cell data getting changed while using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using APACHE POI & Java for reading Excel sheet and create a file of my format. But its noticed that when a number string is read, the code saves it in number format. E.g.

> 12345677

becomes

> 1.2345E7

How to format it correctly?

Current code

```
            Vector cellStoreVector=(Vector)dataHolder.elementAt(0);
            for (int j=0; j < cellStoreVector.size();j++){
                HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell)cellStoreVector.elementAt(j);
                String stringCellValue = myCell.toString();
                bufferedWriter.write(stringCellValue + "|");
            }
```

Comment: As mentioned by @Gagravarr, its better to use DataFormatter. For time being your issue may be solved. But the method I have mentioned may not be working for all other data formats.

Comment: Yes, DataFormatter seems to better function than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me also. Use below code while reading a cell to keep the format as string itself.

```
your_cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

Hope this helps.

Similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072561/how-can-i-read-numeric-strings-in-excel-cells-as-string-not-numbers-with-apach).

Comment: Did you [try reading the Javadocs for that method](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29)? Only they are very clear that this isn't the right way to do it!

Comment: true. But this helped me resolving my issue. The Javadocs clearly stops us from using this method.